# how to get count of '#' in a string?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you count occurences of a string within a string (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c)

**how do I get the count of the occurrences of '#' in a string ?**

something like `int RowFormat = drr[3].ToString("#").Length;`

example string "grtkj####mfr  "

RowFormat must return 4

and yes ^_^ .NET 3.5

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c

Comment: thank you all <3 so many answers

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
int RowFormat = "grtkj####mfr".Count(ch => ch == '#');
```

Comment: Also, when posting a LINQ query, it is still sometimes a good idea to mention that it only works >3.5 unless the questions specifically mentions version.  No better answer given the constraints though.

Answer (score 2):

With LINQ (that's all the rage these days):

```
int RowFormat = drr[3].Count(x => x == '#');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
"grtkj####mfr".Split(new char[]{'#'}).Length-1
```

hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
int RowFormat = new Regex("#").Matches("grtkj####mfr").Count;
```