# Linq: Search a string for all occurrences of multiple spaces

Tags: c#, linq, string

I have a string and i want to find the position of all the occurrences of multiple spaces. Im writing a punctuation checker. I would like to parralelise this operation using parallel linq but in the meantime im just looking for the linq method to get me started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Further to Fredou's answer, a Regex would do this nicely. Regex.Matches returns a MatchCollection that is a (weakly typed) Enumerable. This can be Linq-ified after using the [Cast<T> extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
Regex.Matches(input,@" {2,}").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>new{m.Index,m.Length})
```

Comment: could you bend this easily to return the number of spaces found?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c

Answer (score 2):

this would be better with regex

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, test.Length)
                    from j in Enumerable.Range(0, test.Length)
                    where test[i] == ' ' && (i == 0 || test[i - 1] != ' ') &&
                    (test[j] == ' ' && j == (i + 1))
                    select i;
```

That will give you all of the starting indices where multiple spaces occur.  It's pretty but I'm pretty sure that it works.

edit: There's no need for the join.  This is better.

```
  var s = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, test.Length-1)
                where test[i] == ' ' && (i == 0 || test[i - 1] != ' ') && (test[i+1] == ' ')
                    select i;
```

Comment: Your code is ugly, but it runs 5 times faster than the Regex method! +1

Comment: Very, very ugly :).  I'm not sure how PLINQ handles it.  It would be interesting to see if you get any speedup on multiple cores.