# Count the number of times a string appears within a string

Tags: c#, string, count

I simply have a string that looks something like this:

"7,true,NA,false:67,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false"

All I want to do is to count how many times the string "**true**" appears in that string. I'm feeling like the answer is something like `String.CountAllTheTimesThisStringAppearsInThatString()` but for some reason I just can't figure it out. Help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c/542136#542136

Comment: @jball I think all the solutions there are for counting occurrences of a *character*

Comment: @AakashM, look at the second link. Also, this is the perfect opportunity to provide a more correct (i.e., string based, not char based) answer to that question.

Comment: Refer http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-occurrence

Comment: I'm glad you don't work for Microsoft and get to name methods!

Comment: The linked questions ("This question already has answers here: ") has mostly answers for counting multiple character occurrences, not multiple substring occurrences.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

```
Regex.Matches(input, "true").Count
```

Comment: Based on brevity alone - you win ;)

Comment: there is no matches in C# string.  oops.  Regex.  Nevermind

Comment: Why are we escaping `input` it's not a regular expression?

Comment: @tpower, same question I had. I researched `Regex.Escape` and ran tests in LINQPad to confirm. I edited the edit to remove that.

Answer (score 17):

Probably not the most efficient, but think it's a neat way to do it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CountAllTheTimesThisStringAppearsInThatString("7,true,NA,false:67,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false", "true"));
        Console.WriteLine(CountAllTheTimesThisStringAppearsInThatString("7,true,NA,false:67,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false", "false"));

    }

    static Int32 CountAllTheTimesThisStringAppearsInThatString(string orig, string find)
    {
        var s2 = orig.Replace(find,"");
        return (orig.Length - s2.Length) / find.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: ha ha - I should mark yours as correct just for using my proposed method name. :)

Answer (score 14):

Your regular expression should be `\btrue\b` to get around the 'miscontrue' issue Casper brings up. The full solution would look like this:

```
string searchText = "7,true,NA,false:67,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false";
string regexPattern = @"\btrue\b";
int numberOfTrues = Regex.Matches(searchText, regexPattern).Count;
```

Make sure the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace is included at the top of the file.

Comment: The string variable should not be called Regex - it collides with the .NET Regex class name itself.

Answer (score 5):

This will fail though if the string can contain strings like "miscontrue".

```
   Regex.Matches("7,true,NA,false:67,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false", "true").Count;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here, I'll over-architect the answer using LINQ.  Just shows that there's more than 'n' ways to cook an egg:

```
public int countTrue(string data)
{
    string[] splitdata = data.Split(',');

    var results = from p in splitdata
            where p.Contains("true")
            select p;

    return results.Count();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Linq...

```
string s = "7,true,NA,false:67,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false";
var count = s.Split(new[] {',', ':'}).Count(s => s == "true" );
```

Answer (score 2):

do this , please note that you will have to define the regex for 'test'!!!

```
string s = "7,true,NA,false:67,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false:5,false,NA,false";
string[] parts = (new Regex("")).Split(s);
//just do a count on parts
```