# Java: Find the number of times a word is present in a String (is there something similar to expression of C#)?

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am interesting in finding the number of times a word appears in a String.
I have seen the example of SUN [Matcher Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016522/count-the-number-of-times-a-string-appears-within-a-string) using the matcher (constructs a regex and counts the groups).

I was interested if this is the only way or there is something else like e.g.

[Regex.Matches( input,  "true" ).Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016522/count-the-number-of-times-a-string-appears-within-a-string) in C# (from SO question).

Or in my context:

If I am in a loop using `contains` to check if certain words in the `List` appear in the `String` is there a simple/elegant way to get (on the spot??) the number of times the word occurs (that I already know it exists)?

Comment: Take a look at the Pattern: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html and Matcher: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html classes

Comment: Both of those are since 1.4 so you should be fine

Comment: First and second link in the question redirect to the same page...

Comment: @downvoter:You should be writing some comment as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(toFind, Pattern.LITERAL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
int occurances = p.split(text, -1).length -1;
```

Comment: he he funny, i almost typed the same answer and deleted it after seeing yours

Comment: +1.I like this.If I want case insensitive search I must do `"(?i)"+toFind` right?So should I follow your suggestion as `int occurances = text.split(new StringBuilder("(?i)").append(toFind).toString());` because I am in a loop?

Comment: try something like `text.toLowerCase().split(...)` for a lowercase search in the source, asserting the find pattern is already in lowercase.

Comment: @ortag:How is this better?Doesn't `toLower` create a new `String`?

Comment: If you are in a loop, you can use a compiled pattern.  Creating the StringBuilder yourself won't improve efficiency.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey:But how can I do it, if I know what to append to create the pattern only when I am inside the loop?

Comment: In that case you need to use it inside the loop and you cannot optimise it that way.  One advantage with using Pattern is that you can make it LITERAL to avoid having to quote special characters.

Comment: You mean do `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)"+toFind));`.How is this better?Sorry I lost you :(

Comment: I mean `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(toFind, Pattern.LITERAL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Comment: @Peter Lawrey:Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Peter Lawrey:This does not word if the work is at the end of the String