# While loop to for loop issue

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

I know it's a simple question but can someone help me figure out how to convert this while loop to a for loop. I keep getting an error trying to convert it

```
static string CountLines(string s)
{
    long count = 0;
    int start = 0;

    while ((start = s.IndexOf('\n', start)) != -1)
    {
        count++;
        start++;
    }
    return count.ToString();

}
```

This is the way I tried

```
for (int start = 0; start !=-1 ; start = s.IndexOf('\n', start)) {
   count++;
   start++;
}
```

Comment: "keep getting an error" - what's the error?

Comment: error as in nothing happens

Comment: Do you *need* to convert it to a for-loop?

Comment: Yes I do. I need it

Comment: You are basically counting occurrences of a character in a given string. Namely the `\n` character in your case. Your choice is one of many ways to do that. There are alternatives, some using LINQ, which can be clearer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391481/number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string

Comment: Why are you trying to convert this to a for loop? It is so much better code as a while than as a for loop...

Comment: to run it parallally

Comment: http://rextester.com/MXHL85276

For loop counts correctly where while loop is out by one but seems to work.

Comment: Also [How to count lines in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11189331/719186)

Comment: `for` vs `while` has nothing to do with parallel vs sequential execution. You would need to change the algorithm to do it in parallel, such as just simply checking each character because as you have it now, each subsequent iteration depends on the result of the previous iteration (as you pass the new value of start into `IndexOf`)

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops have the following structure:

```
for (<initialization>; <condition to keep running>; <iterative statements>)
    <loop body>
```

So, first step, you want to move the condition from your `while` loop statement into that middle section of the `for` loop statement.

```
for (something; (start = s.IndexOf('\n', start)) != -1; something;)
```

Now, we can introduce the initialization (`int start = 0`) to the first part and the iterative statement (`start++`) to the last part:

```
for (int start = 0; (start = s.IndexOf('\n', start)) != -1; start++)
{
    count++;
}
```

And there you have it.

Comment: I think the whole point of moving to for was to get rid of the assignment in the conditional.

Comment: @clcto And how did you come to that conclusion? I don't see it mentioned anywhere by OP.

Comment: Because he moved it out of the conditional and it is a common style guideline to not do that.