# Count Text in a String

Tags: c#

I have a string in .NET like so:

```
string str = "Lorem ipsum is great. lorem ipsum Lorem...";
```

I need to get a count of all "Lorem" that matches case as well.  So Lorem should appear twice and ignore the lorem.

Thanks.

Comment: In your text theres only one "Lorem" if you take the case into account.

Comment: What about having "Loremo" instead of "Lorem", does it count?

Comment: no just Lorem and Loremo counts too

Comment: *just* "Lorem" or both "Lorem" and "Loremo"?

Comment: Maybe this question can be merged with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016522/count-the-number-of-times-a-string-appears-within-a-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string str = "Lorem ipsum is great. lorem ipsum Lorem...";
string word = "Lorem";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(str,word).Count);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Linq.

```
String searchWhat = "Lorem";
int count = str.Split(new[]{' ','.'}, StringSplitOptions.None)
               .Count(w => w == searchWhat);
```

demo: http://ideone.com/a9XHln

**Edit**: You have commented that "Lorem Loremo" would count as two, so you want to count all occurences of a given word(case-sentive) even if that word is part of another word. Then you could use `String.Contains`:

```
int count = str.Split(new[]{' ','.'}, StringSplitOptions.None)
               .Count(w => w.Contains(searchWhat));
```

demo: http://ideone.com/fxDGuf

Comment: What if 'str = "Lorem ipsum Lorem. Lorem l"? You'd get 2, not three.

Comment: I admit, it's not true anymore. What about other punctuation? Question comments also indicate that Loremo would have to match (although the comment is a bit ambiguous).

Comment: @NikoDrašković: Edited the answer to take that into account.

Comment: I still don't think its complete: http://ideone.com/EXpBRr . Also, sorry about the nitpicking. Too bad OP isn't here to clarify what he actually wants.

Comment: @NikoDrašković: Of course you can add a `Char[]` with all allowed delimiters between words. The accepted answer is better if OP doesn't want to count words but occurences(even multiple "Lorem" in a single word like "LoremoLorem"). But that's a different approach and requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using `Linq`:

```
string str = "Lorem ipsum is great. lorem ipsum Lorem...";
int loremCount = str.Split(new[]{' ','.',','}, StringSplitOptions.None).Count(s => s.Equals("Lorem"));
```

If you want to consider "Loremo":

```
int loremCount = str.Count(s => s.Equals("Lorem"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents. It will find all instances of "Lorem" case sensative, but it will return a count for things that have "Lorem" in it, like "Loremo" or "thismightnotLorembewhatyouwant".

The question was a bit vague so this answer is a quick solution that conforms to what you requested.

```
string test = "Lorem ipsum is great. lorem ipsum Lorem...";

int pos = -1;
int count = 0;
while ((pos = test.IndexOf("Lorem", pos+1)) != -1)
    count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be able to perform other operations, you can dump the entire string into a List and then you could run Linq queries off off that list.

```
var phrase = "Lorem ipsum...";
var wordList = phrase.Split(' ').ToList();
var loremCount = wordList.Where(x => x.ToLower() == "lorem").Count();
```

This way wordList is reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string text = "Lorem ipsum is great. lorem ipsum Lorem...";
int count = new Regex("Lorem").Matches(text).Count;
```

Hope it will help you. If not please let me know.