# How to get second value via c# StartsWith() method

Tags: c#, .net

```
string text = "Today is a good day for help. **David Diaz He went to school.  **David Diaz like apple. ";
```

How to get how many times the text **David Diaz occurs in the string text?

**UPDATED MY QUESTION**

Comment: You have to be way more specific David. Are you trying to get the first two words?

Comment: `StartsWith()` returns `bool`.  You are never going to get a `string` via `StartsWith()`.

Comment: I think startswiyh method is for this situation is wrong. I just want to get from text "**David Diaz".

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to always get what comes before the second space?

Comment: I updated my question sorry for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you count occurrences of a string within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = "Today is a good day for help. **David Diaz He went to school. **David Diaz like apple. ";

var pos = 0;
var num = 0;
var search = "**David Diaz";
 while ((pos = text.IndexOf(search, pos)) > -1)
{
    num ++;
    pos += search.Length;
}

Console.WriteLine(num);
```

you can try out this in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S5NYCc)

Comment: Thats's very awesome, I'm searching text dynamically. Is it possible to search in the text starts with ** and ends with \t and add them to string list?

Comment: @DavidDiaz That is achievable. But as per Stackoverflow rules, you need to ask one problem per question. create another question for other problems.  don't forget to accept the answer which worked for you . It will be helpful for others to know which answer solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks mate, I've solved my problem half of your answer and half of Timon's answer. You guys rock!

Answer (score 1):

By using StartWhith you can check if the string starts whit ** if it is take the first two words of the string whits will represent the name

```
        string text = "**David Diaz He went to school.";

        if (text.StartsWith("**"))
        {
            var names = text.Split(' ')
                .Take(2)
                .ToArray();
            var fullName = names[0] + " " + names[1];
        }
```

**UPDATE**

As you said in the commend you want to look how many David Diaz occurs in one string, you can use regex for that.

```
  string text = "Today is a good day for help. **David Diaz He went to school. **David Diaz like apple. ";

        int matches = Regex.Matches(
            text,
            @"(?:\S+\s)?\S*David Diaz\S*(?:\s\S+)?",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        ).Count;
```

Comment: Thanks for code but I'm totally dumb. My actual text is string text = "Today is a good day for help. **David Diaz He went to school.  **David Diaz like apple. "; In this code how to get how many **David Diaz have in the string text?

Comment: I've just did something like this. In this way(thanks to you) I can get arraylist with end of "bla bla **David Diaz"
So in this list I need to get **David Diaz by split('****') ?   
var names = allText.Split('\t')               
                    .ToArray();

Comment: See the update I've made this should work. You properly do'n know how to use regex but this is an way (just ignore all the weird symbols XD).

Comment: Thats's very awesome, I'm searching text dynamically. Is it possible to search in the text starts with ** and ends with \t and add them to string list?

Comment: Thanks mate, I've solved my problem half of your answer and half of marked answer. I don'T have a change to choose 2 answers, forgive me :)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**
It sounds like you want to find the number of times a substring exists in your text. For that, you'll want to use RegEx.Matches, as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3016577/682840

or LINQ, as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/541994/682840

**Original Answer:**

`.StartsWith` returns true/false if the string begins with the search string you provide.  If you're wanting to know where a substring exists within your text, you'll need to use [`.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) or a Regular Expression for more advanced scenarios.

`IndexOf` will return the location in the text where your provided search string starts (or -1 if it isn't found).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm totally dumb. My actual text is string text = "Today is a good day for help. **David Diaz He went to school.  **David Diaz like apple. "; In this code how to get how many **David Diaz have in the string text?