# Minimize LINQ string token counter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, string

Followup on answer to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035563/extract-keywords-from-text-in-net/4035757#4035757).

Is there a way to further reduce this, avoiding the external `String.Split` call?  The goal is an associative container of `{token, count}`.

```
string src = "for each character in the string, take the rest of the " +
    "string starting from that character " +
    "as a substring; count it if it starts with the target string";

string[] target = src.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

var results = target.GroupBy(t => new
{
    str = t,
    count = target.Count(sub => sub.Equals(t))
});
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `string.Split` to tokenize?

Comment: @Kirk - it's not that I want to avoid the Split, I was just looking for a more elegant and efficient (if possible) formulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have it right now, it will work (to some extent) but is terribly inefficient.  As is, the result is an enumeration of groupings, not the (word, count) pairs you might be thinking.

That overload of `GroupBy()` takes a function to select the key.  You are effectively performing that calculation for every item in the collection.  Without going the route of using regular expressions ignoring punctuation, it should be written like so:

```
string src = "for each character in the string, take the rest of the " +
             "string starting from that character " +
             "as a substring; count it if it starts with the target string";

var results = src.Split()               // default split by whitespace
                 .GroupBy(str => str)   // group words by the value
                 .Select(g => new
                              {
                                  str = g.Key,      // the value
                                  count = g.Count() // the count of that value
                              });

// sort the results by the words that were counted
var sortedResults = results.OrderByDescending(p => p.str);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the one that best answers the question. And also for the clarification - I am a Linq newbie and that extra info is helpful.

Comment: How to add OrderByDescending here?

Comment: @Sphynx: Just add the call to `OrderByDescending()` at the point you wish to sort.  Just be aware of what items you are sorting within the query.  e.g., If put before the `GroupBy()`, you're sorting strings.  If after, you're sorting groupings of strings.  If after the `Select()`, you're sorting by the anonymous type.  I'll update to incorporate your request.

Answer (score 3):

While 3-4 times slower, the Regex method is arguably more accurate:

```
string src = "for each character in the string, take the rest of the " +
    "string starting from that character " +
    "as a substring; count it if it starts with the target string";

var regex=new Regex(@"\w+",RegexOptions.Compiled);
var sw=new Stopwatch();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var dic=regex
        .Matches(src)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m=>m.Value)
        .GroupBy(s=>s)
        .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key,g=>g.Count());
    if(i==1000)sw.Start();
}
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

sw.Reset();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var dic=src
        .Split(' ')
        .GroupBy(s=>s)
        .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key,g=>g.Count());
    if(i==1000)sw.Start();
}
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

For instance, the Regex method won't count `string` and `string,` as two separate entries, and will correctly tokenise `substring` instead of `substring;`.

EDIT

Read your previous question and realise my code doesn't quite conform to your spec. Regardless, it still demonstrates the advantage/cost of using Regex.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LINQ version without `ToDictionary()`, which may add unnecessary overhead depending on your needs...

```
var dic = src.Split(' ').GroupBy(s => s, (str, g) => new { str, count = g.Count() });
```

Or in query syntax...

```
var dic = from str in src.Split(' ')
          group str by str into g
          select new { str, count = g.Count() };
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of `String.Split` doesn't leave many options on the table. One option is `Regex.Matches` as [spender demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038836/minimize-linq-string-token-counter/4039004#4039004), and another is `Regex.Split` (which doesn't give us anything new).

Rather than grouping you could use either of these approaches:

```
var target = src.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var result = target.Distinct()
                   .Select(s => new { Word = s, Count = target.Count(w => w == s) });

// or dictionary approach
var result = target.Distinct()
                   .ToDictionary(s => s, s => target.Count(w => w == s));
```

The `Distinct` call is needed to avoid duplicate items. I went ahead and expanded the characters to split on to get the actual words devoid of punctuation. I found the first approach to be the quickest using spender's benchmarking code.

Back to the requirement to order the results from your previously referenced question, you could easily extend the first approach as follows:

```
var result = target.Distinct()
                   .Select(s => new { Word = s, Count = target.Count(w => w == s) })
                   .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count);

// or in query form

var result = from s in target.Distinct()
             let count = target.Count(w => w == s)
             orderby count descending
             select new { Word = s, Count = count };
```

EDIT: got rid of the Tuple since the anonymous type was close at hand.