# How to enumerate Linq results?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, string

Referring to this topic: [Minimize LINQ string token counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038836/minimize-linq-string-token-counter)
And using the following provided code:

```
string src = "for each character in the string, take the rest of the " +
             "string starting from that character " +
             "as a substring; count it if it starts with the target string";

var results = src.Split()               // default split by whitespace
                 .GroupBy(str => str)   // group words by the value
                 .Select(g => new
                              {
                                  str = g.Key,      // the value
                                  count = g.Count() // the count of that value
                              });
```

I need to enumerate all values (keywords and number of occurrences) and load them into NameValueCollection. Due to my very limited Linq knowledge, can't figure out how to make it. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't guess why you want to put anything in a `NameValueCollection`, but is there some reason why

```
foreach (var result in results)
    collection.Add(result.str, result.count.ToString());
```

is not sufficient?

(EDIT:  Changed accessor to `Add`, which may be better for your use case.)

If the answer is "no, that works" you should probably stop and figure out what the hell the above code is doing before using it in your project.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use collection.Add, since NameValueCollections can have multiple keys?

Comment: Probably, yeah.  I was unfamiliar with `NameValueCollections`.  Fixed it.

Comment: I perfectly understand what the above code is doing, but most of the time I use a different .NET language, so I'm new to both C# and Linq :) Didn't think it was so simple, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your particular problem could just as easily use a Dictionary instead of a NameValueCollection. I forget if this is the correct ToDictionary syntax, but just google the ToDictionary() method:

```
Dictionary<string, int> useADictionary = results.ToDictionary(x => x.str, x => x.count);
```

Comment: The second argument in your call is an assignment instead of an anonymous function, but +1 for suggesting a dictionary instead of a NameValueCollection!

Comment: And now it has been fixed.  Disregard previous comment up to "+1..."

Answer (score 1):

You certainly want a `Dictionary` instead of `NameValueCollection`. The whole point is to show **unique** tokens (`string`s) with each token's occurrence count (an `int`), yes?

`NameValueCollection` is a special-purpose collection that requires string and key and value - `Dictionary<string, int>` is the mainstream .Net way to associate a unique `string` key with its corresponding `int` value.

Take a look at the various [System.Collections namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145035.aspx) to understand what each is intended to achieve.  Typically these days, `System.Collections.Generic` is the most widely-seen, with `System.Collections.Concurrent` for multithreaded programs.