# finding occurrences of string within a string

Tags: c#

What is the quickest and most efficient way of finding a string within another string.

For instance I have this text;

> "Hey @ronald and @tom where are we going this weekend"

However I want to find the strings which start with "@".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Regular expressions.

```
string test = "Hey @ronald and @tom where are we going this weekend";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"@[\S]+");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(test);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

That will output:

```
@ronald
@tom
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Regular Expressions:

```
string data = "Hey @ronald and @tom where are we going this weekend";

var result = Regex.Matches(data, @"@\w+");

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
string s = "Hey @ronald and @tom where are we going this weekend";
var list = s.Split(' ').Where(c => c.StartsWith("@"));
```

Comment: yes, if you want to remove them i guess `Regex` will be the best to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after speed:

```
string source = "Hey @ronald and @tom where are we going this weekend";
int count = 0;
foreach (char c in source) 
  if (c == '@') count++;
```

If you want a one liner:

```
string source = "Hey @ronald and @tom where are we going this weekend";
var count = source.Count(c => c == '@');
```

Check here [How would you count occurrences of a string within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c#comment12361421_541954)

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = "hallo world"
int pos = str.IndexOf("wo",0)
```

Comment: still the question is what to do if you expect more than one match, as in the example - that's where the efficiency kicks in