# Count the number of tabs in a string

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you count occurences of a string within a string (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c)

I am reading a file in line by line and need to count the number of tabs that each string contains. How can I get a count of the tabs i.e. \t from the string.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9):

```
uint howManyTabs(string s) {
    return (uint)s.Count(ch => ch == '\t');
}
```

Comment: Why cast to uint?

Comment: Because it has to be a non-negative integer?

Comment: Because the function returns `uint`...

Comment: Why does the function return uint and not simply int?

Comment: @dtb, to make it explicit that the return value is never less than zero. That's what an unsigned int is for, after all. As far as I understand, things like Count return int in order to be CLS compliant, which is probably not an issue here.