# c# if String Contains 2 "hallo"

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you count occurences of a string within a string (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c)

I want to check if a String contains 2 things..

```
String hello = "hellohelloaklsdhas";

if hello.Contains(*hello 2 Times*); -> True
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you want exactly 2, or at least 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a regex :)

```
return Regex.Matches(hello, "hello").Count == 2;
```

This matches the string `hello` for the pattern `"hello"` and returns true if the count is 2.

Comment: In my case this wasn't working because the string I was looking for was a dot("."). So instead of "hello" I changed it to "\." and it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(hello,@"(.*hello.*){2,}"))
```

I guess you meant "hello", and this will match a string with at least 2 "hello" (not exactly 2 "hello")

Comment: +1 for the matching with a count regex :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int Matches(this string text, string pattern)
    {
        int count = 0, i = 0;
        while ((i = text.IndexOf(pattern, i)) != -1)
        {
            i += pattern.Length;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s1 = "Sam's first name is Sam.";
        string s2 = "Dot Net Perls is about Dot Net";
        string s3 = "No duplicates here";
        string s4 = "aaaa";

        Console.WriteLine(s1.Matches("Sam"));  // 2
        Console.WriteLine(s1.Matches("cool")); // 0
        Console.WriteLine(s2.Matches("Dot"));  // 2
        Console.WriteLine(s2.Matches("Net"));  // 2
        Console.WriteLine(s3.Matches("here")); // 1
        Console.WriteLine(s3.Matches(" "));    // 2
        Console.WriteLine(s4.Matches("aa"));   // 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex, and check the length of the result of Matches function. If it's two you win.

Answer (score 1):

`new Regex("hello.*hello").IsMatch(hello)`

or

`Regex.IsMatch(hello, "hello.*hello")`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a regular expression MatchCollection you can get this easily:

```
MatchCollection matches;

Regex reg = new Regex("hello"); 

matches = reg.Matches("hellohelloaklsdhas");
return (matches.Count == 2);
```

Comment: why do you need `matchposition`?

Comment: @Vlad: You don't. It was a holdover from a copy/paste. Thanks.

Comment: Or you could just use the one liner static method.

Comment: There are a myriad number of ways to accomplish this task. I personally like @m0skit0's answer the best. I was tempted to point out that your first answer used .Match instead of .Matches but I figured you'd catch on to it eventually :)

Answer (score 1):

#### IndexOf

You can use the `IndexOf` method to get the index of a certain string. This method has an overload that accepts a starting point, from where to look. When the specified string is not found, `-1` is returned.

Here is an example that should speak for itself.

```
var theString = "hello hello bye hello";
int index = -1;
int helloCount = 0;

while((index = theString.IndexOf("hello", index+1)) != -1)
{
    helloCount++;
}

return helloCount==2;
```

#### Regex

Another way to get the count is to use Regex:

```
return (Regex.Matches(hello, "hello").Count == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf:

```
int FirstIndex = str.IndexOf("hello");
int SecondIndex = str.IndexOf("hello", FirstIndex + 1);
if(FirstIndex != -1 && SecondIndex != -1)
{
  //contains 2 or more hello
}
else
{
   //contains not
}
```

or if you want exactly 2: `if(FirstIndex != -1 && SecondIndex != -1 && str.IndexOf("hello", SecondIndex) == -1)`