# Why I cannot compile a LINQ command

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, linq

I am using C#, WinForms, In VS2010 Pro and trying to run one line of code:

```
var count = before.Count(c => c == '/');
```

which I got from here: [How would you count occurrences of a string within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c/541988#541988)

but it doesn't recognize Count method on Strings, so it gives error and doesn't compile.
How should I fix it? what is missing?

Comment: What is the type of `before`?

Comment: @DBM From the question I think we can infer `before` is a `String`.

Comment: @BDotA - if you haven't heard of it, I'd recommend Jetbrains resharper. It picks up things like missing references and a keyboard shortcut Alt+Enter adds the namespace + references the dll

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson Oh yeah, I love Resharper, but my trial expired months ago :(

Comment: @BDotA only £116 quid for personal C# only ;-) Open source license is free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you are missing a using directive for the `System.Linq` namespace or less likely, a reference to the `System.Core.dll` assembly.

Try inserting this at the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

If that doesn't fix it, right-click on your project from "Solution Explorer", choose "Add Reference" from the context-menu and then ensure that `System.Core.dll` is referenced.

Also ensure that you are targeting .NET 3.5 or later (there are workarounds for .NET 2.0, such as [LinqBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/)).

Comment: I right click on References and try to find a System.Core,  but cannot find it

Comment: Which version of the framework are you targeting? The list will be filtered to assemblies supported by that version.

Comment: @Yuck: I have .NT 4.0 and also SP1 of .NET 3.5 according to http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/

Comment: Ok, Fixed it, the problem that it was not showing it was because on Build Properties of the application it was set on .NET 3.0, Although I had even .NET 4.0 but build of project was on .NET 3.0 so it was not listing System.LINQ.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `Enumerable.Count()` extension method is available since .NET Framework 3.5 it is possible that you've not targeted right version in your C# project or have not installed .NET Framework 3.5 at all.

[MSDN, version Information:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx)

```
.NET Framework
Supported in: 4, 3.5

.NET Framework Client Profile
Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
```

Comment: I searched to add System.Core to references but it doesn't list it. My VS Installations is corrupted maybe?

Comment: Thanks but I have VS2010 so I think it is .NET 4.0 actually

Comment: Ok, Fixed it, the problem that it was not showing it was because on Build Properties of the application it was set on .NET 3.0, Although I had even .NET 4.0 but build of project was on .NET 3.0 so it was not listing System.LINQ.  Thanks