# Determine if all characters in a string are the same

Tags: c#, string, contains

I have a situation where I need to try and filter out fake SSN numbers.  From what I've seen so far if they are fake they're all the same number or 123456789.  I can filter for the last one, but is there an easy way to determine if all the characters are the same?

Comment: s != null && s.Length > 1 && s[s.Length - 1] == s[0]

Comment: Just use the first character in the string and use the answers to this previous question to count the number of occurances:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391481/number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string

Comment: How many times will the problem be in other places? If needed offset by uncertainty required...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

return (ssn.[Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx).Count() == 1)

Comment: I believe you mean `ssn.Distinct().Count()`

Answer (score 11):

This method should do the trick:

```
public static bool AreAllCharactersSame(string s)
{
    return s.Length == 0 || s.All(ch => ch == s[0]);
}
```

Explanation: if a string's length is 0, then of course all characters are the same.  Otherwise, a string's characters are all the same if they are all equal to the first.

Comment: What if it's only 1 char in length :P

Comment: @Jay A 1-character string has all the same character, so a general "find out if this string's characters are all the same" method should return `true`.

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of this problem, since we are talking about SSN. You can check and use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9505/SSN-Validation-Web-Service) CodeProject demo project to validate SSN. Though this is in VB.Net, I guess you can come up with the same idea.

Comment: Coding up the restrictions here is probably a better solution than any filter you think up.

Comment: but how would you validate an SSN if values entered were the fake one? for example 123456798? There are number of rules that we need to implement with our validation. Checking if all characters are the same wouldn't suffice to make it reliable.

Comment: I wasn't clear.  I meant that to OP's problem would be best solved by implementing all the rules in the project linked here, rather than  creating a few simple filters similar to the one they proposed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Grab first character, and loop.

```
var ssn = "222222222";
var fc = ssn[0];

for(int i=0; i<ssn.Length; i++)
{
    if(ssn[i]!=fc)
        return false;
}

return true;
```

of course you should also check length of `ssn`

Comment: String is null this breaks :p

Comment: Ya.. Empty string also break this. OP should take care this problem.

Comment: Also, would be better if the for loop starts at 2nd character, since it doesn't make sense to check the first character with itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] chrAry = inputStr.ToCharArray();
char first = chrAry[0];

var recordSet = from p in chrAry where p != first select p;
return !recordSet.Any();
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you think about that:

```
"jhfbgsdjkhgkldhfbhsdfjkgh".Distinct().Skip(1).Any()
```

To avoid counting the whole number of character? you are supposed to check before null or empty.