# How can I check that the string only contains one specific character?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
dr["DomainName"].ToString().Contains("*")
```

checks `dr["DomainName"]` contains the char `*`, but the condition may also be true if it contains other chars.

How can I check that the string only contains one char and this char is a `*`

Comment: erm, `dr["DomainName"].ToString() == "*"`

Comment: If you mean that the string is one or more * & nothing else - then check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027475/c-sharp-determine-if-all-characters-in-a-string-are-the-same

Comment: You're searching for * in the entire string by using 'Contains',so this will turn out to be true when the string contains * even once (atleast) along with other characters.But if you are want to check if the string is just * (only), you should be using the solution posted by jodrell. Anyways, why is this question being downvoted? I'm curious.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to compare them using `String.Equals` or `==`

```
if(dr.Field<string>("DomainName") == "*")
{
    // ...
}
```

`String.Contains` is a sub-string search whereas `==` compares the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

A simple == should do it

```
dr["DomainName"].ToString() == "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to compare the `string` to `*`:

```
dr["DomainName"].ToString() == "*";
```

Answer (score 1):

string.Contains determines whether or not the given string *contains* the argument, whether that be a single character, or a sub-string that you wish to find.

For example, `("Hello World").Contains("Hello")` as well as `("Hello World").Contains('e')` would both result in true, as the given string (In this case, "Hello World") contains the given argument in both cases. More on string.Contains [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx).

In your case, however, I understand you're simply trying to determine if the given string *is*  an asterisk, rather than if it *contains* one. In this case, string.Contains isn't needed! Just do a simple comparison like so: `dr["DomainName"].ToString() == "*"`

Correct me if I misinterpreted your question in any way, and feel free to comment on this answer if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the correct condition, to check, if it is equal to *.

```
dr["DomainName"].ToString() == "*"
```