# Trying to return true if all the letters in a string are the same

Tags: java, char, operators

What I have so far:

```
 public boolean allSameLetter(String str)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        int charb4 = i--;
        if ( str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(charb4))
        {
        return false;
        }

        if ( i == str.length())
        {
        return true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Please excuse any inefficiencies if any; still relatively new to coding in general. Am I lacking some knowledge in terms of using operators and .charAt() together? Is it illogical? Or is my error elsewhere?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly? comparing two strings?

Comment: One thing: name your variables completely, don't abbreviate them. You're decreasing `i` so you enter an infinite loop...

Comment: Having the code check a string to see if its composed of the same letter. (ie. "aaa", "oooo", "ddddd")

Comment: Related post - [Determine if all characters in a string are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16027475/465053)

Answer (score 6):

Using regex:

```
return str.matches("^(.)\\1*$");
```

Using streams:

```
str.chars().allMatch(c -> c == str.charAt(0));
```

Other:

```
return str.replace(String.valueOf(str.charAt(0), "").length() == 0;
```

Comment: Could you explain that first regex please?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the below steps:

(1) Get the first character (i.e., 0th index)

(2) Check the first character is the same with subsequent characters, if not return `false` (and comes out from method)

(3) If all chars match i.e., processing goes till the end of the method and returns `true`

```
  public boolean allSameLetter(String str) {
  char c1 = str.charAt(0);
  for(int i=1;i<str.length;i++) {
      char temp = str.charAt(i);
      if(c1 != temp) {
         //if chars does NOT match, 
         //just return false from here itself,
         //there is no need to verify other chars
         return false;
      }
  }
  //As it did NOT return from above if (inside for)
  //it means, all chars matched, so return true
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew said, you are decreasing `i` within your for loop. You can fix this by changing it to `int charb4 = i - 1;`. As for making your code more efficient you could condense it down to this.

```
public boolean allSameLetter(String str) {
    for(char c : str.toCharArray())
        if(c != str.charAt(0)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment if you don't understand a part of it :)

```
 public boolean allSameLetter(String str)
 {
 for (int i = 1; i < str.length() -1; i++)
  {
    if ( str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i+1))
    {
    return false;
    }
  } 
 return true
}
```

-1 is there since I am checking the current value in the array, then the next value in the array, thus I need to stop a place earlier.

If the loop if statement is never entered, it will make it far enough into the code to return true

Comment: It can be made more efficiently, but I chose to keep your code in order to help you. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a for loop that searches through the length of the String - 1. this way the program will not crash because of a 3 letter word with the program trying to get the 4th letter. This is what works for me:

```
public boolean allSameLetter(String str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< str.length()-1; i++){
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i+1)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if((new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(s.toCharArray()))).size()==1)
            return true;
            return false;`

This should be enough

Comment: An explanation would be helpful. Also, your answer does not appear to match the asker's skill level.

Answer (score -1):

The bug is caused by

```
int charb4 = i--;
```

this line is equal to

```
int charb4 = i-1;
i=i-1;
```

Because of this, your loop will never stop. 
The easiest way to fix this

```
public boolean allSameLetter(String str)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
  {
     if ( str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i-1))
     {
       return false;
     }
  } 
}
```