# is there a ready method which gives you the repetition of word in a string in c#?

Tags: c#, string

I need your help,is there a ready method which gives you the repetition of word in a string in c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of occurrences of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391481/number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Is that what the question is asking? I understood is as "is there a method which repeats a word".

Comment: do a simple google search @Mohammad come on now there are so many examples of this on the internet for example http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-occurrence

Comment: Obviously __not a duplicate__ OP is not asking about characters or strings but about word..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple regex will do it:

```
string str = "abcabcabcabcabc"; // 5 times
int cnt = Regex.Matches(str ,"abc").Count; // 5
```

Comment: Well, that's you. I wouldn't.

Comment: The op asks about words!

Comment: See here for a [correct Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209049/c-regex-match-whole-words)