# 'if' character count or different values

Tags: c#

Please excuse the rubbish title, I don't know how to word it properly. I am wondering how I can use this code:

```
int cnt = 0;
foreach (char c in test) {
  if (c == '&') cnt++;
}
```

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391481/number-of-occurrences-of-a-) and instead of adding 1 to the count for 'just' `&`, add 1 to the count for `&` or `@` or `%`?

Comment: Use it for what? What is the exact problem you are having and what have you done so far to try to solve it?

Comment: There is no need to state the problem when I made it clear what I wanted in the question

Comment: There is every need to state what you have already tried, SO isn't a free code service, it is here for help with existing problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy, just add more conditions:

```
int cnt = 0;
foreach (char c in test) {
    if (c == '&' || c == '@' || c == '%') cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! A helpful answer. I will mark as the answer when I can. I feel so stupid that I didn't use the or operator :(

Answer (score 7):

You can directly count using `.Count` and with using `Linq`

```
 var cnt = test.Count(c => c == '&' || c == '@' || c == '%');
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Regex:

```
cnt = Regex.Matches(test, "[&@%]").Count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string pattern = "&@%";
int cnt = 0;
foreach (char c in test)
{
    if (pattern.IndexOf(c) != -1) cnt++;
}
```