# how to count Enter in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you count occurences of a string within a string (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c)

I have a string that has multiple sub-strings and Enter (special character by pressing Enter key) between them.

Can you please guide me how to write a regular expression that counts Enter keys between words ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a _regular expression_ for counting the number of occurrences of a character in a string?  That's overkill.  Just count the characters some other way.  Iterate through the characters.  Or perhaps there is a library function.

Comment: Would the "Enter"s be `"\r\n"` (`CRLF`), `"\n"` (`LF`) or `"\r"` (`CR`)?

Comment: "Hey, I have a problem that is related to strings. I must need a regex."

Comment: Lots of ways here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the line break symbol used you may have to change to just `\r` or just `\n`.

```
var numberLineBreaks = Regex.Matches(input, @"\r\n").Count;
```

Comment: thanks, it works for me. I really need of this.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a regex, you're just counting strings. Specifically you're just counting `Environment.Newline`s. There's lots of ways to do that; several are described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c). Here's one which looks inefficient but performs surprisingly well:

```
int count1 = source.Length - source.Replace(Environment.Newline, "").Length;
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be a regular expression? There are probably easier ways... for example, you could use `string[] array = String.Split('\n');` to create an array of the substrings, then get the count with `array.Length;`

Comment: You probably need to subtract one from the result.

Comment: This would be extremely inefficient and wasteful, since the OP only need a count.

Answer (score 0):

You could do by simply counting the newlines:

```
int start = -1;
int count = 0;
while ((start = text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, start + 1)) != -1)
    count++;
return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Code,

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
         long a = CountLinesInString("This is an\r\nawesome website.");
         Console.WriteLine(a);

         long b = CountLinesInStringSlow("This is an awesome\r\nwebsite.\r\nYeah.");
         Console.WriteLine(b);
         }

         static long CountLinesInString(string s)
         {
          long count = 1;
          int start = 0;
          while ((start = s.IndexOf('\n', start)) != -1)
          {
              count++;
               start++;
          } 
          return count;
         }

         static long CountLinesInStringSlow(string s)
         {
          Regex r = new Regex("\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
          MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s);
          return mc.Count + 1;
         }
 }
```