# Replace the same line if contains any word in it in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Example:
If there is a line http://google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;ord=$RANDOM? which contains adi in it, wants it to be replaced with http://google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;click=$CLICK;ord=$RANDOM? and rest all other text to be same with no change.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly simple task:

```
string url = @"http://google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;ord=$RANDOM?";

if (url.Contains(@"/adi/"))
{
    int pos = url.IndexOf(";ord"); //// Find first occurence of Ord parameter
    url = url.Insert(pos, ";click=$CLICK"); //// Insert text at position
}
```

Edit: To accomplish the task for multiple occurences I used a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c) thread.

```
{
    string url = "<google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;ord=$RANDOM?>; <google.com/adi/727412;sz=300x250;ord=$RANDOM?>";
    string searchString = @"/adi/";

    int n = 0;

    while ((n = url.IndexOf(searchString, n)) != -1)
    {
        n += searchString.Length;
        int pos = url.IndexOf('?', n);
        url = url.Insert(pos, ";click=$CLICK");
    }
}
```

Comment: But than what if we have multiple of such strings with different IDs. Example : string  URL =<http://google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;ord=$RANDOM?>
<http://google.com/adi/727412;sz=300x250;ord=$RANDOM?>,

With the above code it will change for 728x90 and not for 300x250. Please help.

Comment: Please see my improved answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string url = "http://google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;ord=$RANDOM?";
        if(url.Contains("adi")) url = "http://google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;click=$CLICK;ord=$RANDOM?";


        string url = "blablablablablahttp://google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;ord=$RANDOM?blablabla";
        if(url.Contains("adi")) url.Replace("http://google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;ord=$RANDOM?", "http://google.com/adi/727412;sz=728x90;click=$CLICK;ord=$RANDOM?");
```

Comment: Looking only for "adi" can produce wrong results as you will find occurences inside words like for example "stadium".

Comment: mine was just a quick dirty solution ;) i like your's more aswell!