# How to find the position of occurrence of character in C#?

Tags: c#

I have

```
string input = "XXXX-NNNN-A/N";
string[] separators = { "-", "/" };
```

I need to find out the position of occurrence of the seperators in the string.

The output will be

```
5 "-" 
10 "-"
12 "/"
```

How to do in C#?

Comment: Have you tried the documentation?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx

Comment: Just follow this duplicate post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c?rq=1

Comment: Look at string.IndexOf(...), string.IndexOfAny(...), string.LastIndexOf(...), string.LastIndexOfAny(...) methods.

Comment: Do those seperators have to be strings or can they be chars?

Comment: Do you need to know which one of the separators was found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string input = "XXXX-NNNN-A/N";
char[] seperators = new[] { '/', '-' };
Dictionary<int, char> positions = new Dictionary<int,char>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    if (seperators.Contains(input[i]))
        positions.Add(i + 1, input[i]);

foreach(KeyValuePair<int, char> pair in positions)
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " \"" + pair.Value + "\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < separators.Length; j++)
    {
        if (input[i] == separators[j])
            Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + "\"" + separators[j] + "\"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get a zero-based position index from the [`String.IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> FindThem(string theInput)
{
    List<int> theList = new List<int>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < theInput.Length)
        if (theInput.IndexOfAny(new[] { '-', '/' }, i) >= 0)
        {
            theList.Add(theInput.IndexOfAny(new[] { '-', '/' }, i) + 1);
            i = theList.Last();
        }
        else break;
    return theList;
}
```

Comment: Should be `>= 0`, this way if the string starts with a separator, it will be found.

Comment: @Matthew You caught me in mid edit. You are, of course, correct.

Comment: Why: i = theList.Last() + 1; I think i++ would be enough.

Comment: @MartinMulder No. If i=0 and a separator was found at, say, 5 - you'll be checking from 1 and finding 5 again (If you'd use i++).

Comment: @ispiro: Yes, but you are putting `i` (thus 0) to the list, not 5.

Comment: -1: He asks for a combination of positions + their index, not only their indexes.

Comment: @MartinMulder Corrected. As for your second comment - I don't think the OP really cares about that - I think his example was only to illustrate the question. But you may be right.

Answer (score 1):

Gotta love LINQ for stuff like this. Given this:

```
string input = "XXXX-NNNN-A/N";
string[] separators = {"-", "/"};
```

Perform the search using:

```
var found = input.Select((c, i) => new {c = c, i = i})
            .Where(x => separators.ToList().Contains(x.c.ToString()));
```

Output it for example like this:

```
found.ToList().ForEach(element => 
                        Console.WriteLine(element.i + " \"" + element.c + "\""));
```

Comment: Or just `("XXXX-NNNN-A/N".Select((c, i) => new { c = c, i = i }).Where(x => (new[] { "-", "/" }).ToList().Contains(x.c.ToString()))).ToList().ForEach(element => Console.WriteLine(element.i + " \"" + element.c + "\""));` :)

Comment: Yes, possible, of course. I was, however, trying to be slightly more pedagogical here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int index = 0;                                                  // Starting at first character
char[] separators = "-/".ToCharArray();
while (index < input.Length) {
    index = input.IndexOfAny(separators, index);              // Find next separator
    if (index < 0) break;
    Debug.WriteLine((index+1).ToString() + ": " + input[index]);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Why convert your seperators into a char array every other iteration?

Comment: Why the `index.ToString()`?

Comment: @MartinMulder: `"-/".ToCharArray()` should surely be done outside the loop, that's right.

Comment: @MartinMulder: `index.ToString()` because this line makes a string concatenation. `index + ":" + ...` is not intuitive for me, because index is a int.

Comment: You forgot to add 1 to the index.

Comment: I did... your program will produce `4 "-"` and not `5 "-"` as requested.