# What is the best way to find length of split characters from the given string by using String.Split() Method or Linq Lambda Expression in C#

Tags: c#, string, linq, lambda, split

I have String called "RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa". I want to know number of "a" characters available in the give String. As per my knowledge I found two ways to find the count. That are: 1) By using String.Split() 2) Linq Lambda Expression

## My Observations:

1) If i use String.Split() it is returning wrong result
2) If i use Linq Lambda Expression it is returning correct result.

Here my doubt is how can i get the count of the given split character from the given string by using String.Split()

And also please suggest me which is the best way to get count of the given split character from the given string either "String.Split()" or "Linq Lambda" expression?

## Please find the complete example:

```
                                                                                                                   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SplitData
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'a');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'r');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'R');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'm');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'd');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'g');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 's');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'o');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'c');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'u');
            SplitData("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'f');


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void SplitData(string data,char split)
        {

            // using lambda expresion
            int len = data.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.ToString().ToLower().Contains(split)).Count();  
            Console.WriteLine("Total '" + split + "' available are:{0} using lambda", len.ToString());

            //using normal split function
            len = data.Split(split).Length;

            Console.WriteLine("Total '" + split + "' available are:{0} using normal split", len.ToString());


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you count occurrences of a string within a string (C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c)

Comment: Those two functions are not equivalent. In the first you take String.ToLower() in the second you take the string "as is".

Comment: Hi Jon. This not a duplicate question of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c. Please read question carefully before telling as a duplicate question.. because i am asking is:
>>>>>> refer it in above question
Here my doubt is how can i get the count of the given split character from the given string by using String.Split()

And also please suggest me which is the best way to get count of the given split character from the given string either "String.Split()" or "Linq Lambda" expression?

Comment: @RamaSubbaReddyM: the linked question addresses shows how to do it with String.Split(), and discusses which option is "best". It is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string str = "RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa";
int countA = str.Count(r => r == 'a');
```

If you want case insensitive count then:

```
string str = "RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa";
char searchChar = 'a';
int countA = str.Count(r => char.ToUpperInvariant(r) == char.ToUpperInvariant(searchChar));
```

If you ask for best option between `string.Split` and Linq `Count`, then IMO, LINQ is more readable. I am not sure about the performance but I suspect LINQ version to be faster.

---

If you want to use `string.Split` and make it case insensitive then construct a character array of two elements, *(with upper case and lower case)* and then use `Split` like:

```
string str = "RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa";
char searchChar = 'a';
char[] delimeters = new char[2];
delimeters[0] = char.ToLowerInvariant(searchChar);
delimeters[1] = char.ToUpperInvariant(searchChar);
var count = str.Split(delimeters).Length - 1;
```

Comment: Hi Habib,how can i get the count of the given split character from the given string by using String.Split()?. I am already getting correct count by using linq concepts.

Comment: @RamaSubbaReddyM `data.Split(split).Length - 1` (Note this is case sensitive)

Comment: @RamaSubbaReddyM, you can do `var count = str.Split(new[] { 'a', 'A' }).Length - 1;` but you have to construct an array of upper case and lower case character to make it case insensitive.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the difference (in results at least) between using `Count` and using `Split` and then counting the size of the split set. Won't that return the exact same count?

Comment: @RamaSubbaReddyM, I just updated my answer which is using `string.Split` to count occurrence of a char *(case insensitive)*

Comment: @Habib, Thanks for solutions. There was a small issue in your solution. If i use  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries i am getting wrong result otherwise getting correct result.       Example:                                                data.Split(new char[] { char.ToLowerInvariant(split),  char.ToUpperInvariant(split) },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length - 1;

Comment: @Habib, Suppose i want to remove empty data what will happen?. any how thanks for the solution..

Comment: @RamaSubbaReddyM, if you remove empty data, you will not get the correct count, since `Adjacent delimiters yield an array element that contains an empty string ("")` Read more about [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx). So if there are adjacent `a` in your string, `RemoveEntrieis` would give you wrong result.

Comment: I would turn the input string to `lower case` and then use `Split('a')` only without having to care about `'a' or 'A'`

Answer (score 2):

You mean you want to count the occurances of a letter? Like this?

```
String data = "RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa";
Char letter = 'a';
Int32 totalOccurances = data.Count(character => character == letter);
```

Comment: Hi Sircidesakit,how can i get the count of the given split character from the given string by using String.Split()?. I am already getting correct count by using linq concepts.

Comment: `The count of the given split character`? Example?

Comment: Yes i want an example how to get number of split characters('a' count) available in the given string by using String.Split('a')

Answer (score 2):

For case-insensitive comparison, you can use a [`StringComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.StringComparer.aspx) instance or equivalent [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) enum.. As far as how you want to write it, pick your poison. =)

```
// caller specifies comparison type
int Count1(string str, char searchChar, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    string searchStr = searchChar.ToString();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        if (string.Equals(searchStr, str[i].ToString(), comparison))
            count++;
    return count;
}
// ordinal comparison
int Count2(string str, char searchChar)
{
    string searchStr = searchChar.ToString();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        if (searchChar == str[i])
            count++;
    return count;
}
// ordinal comparison
int Count3(string str, char searchChar)
{
    return str.Split(searchChar).Length - 1;
}
// ordinal comparison
int Count4(string str, char searchChar)
{
    return str.Count(c => c == searchChar);
}
// caller specifies comparison type
int Count5(string str, char searchChar, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    string searchStr = searchChar.ToString();
    return str.Count(c => string.Equals(c.ToString(), searchStr, comparison));
}
```

Comment: Holy Cow that's thorough!

Answer (score 1):

Not a fancy LINQ solution but nevertheless

```
int count = CountChar("RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa", 'a');
.....

int CountChar(string input, char toFind)
{
    int count = 0;
    int pos = -1;
    while((pos = input.IndexOf(toFind, pos+1)) != -1)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

[String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx) starting from a position
and there is also the [case insensitive option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424.aspx)

EDIT: Well now I was curious and decided to measure the timing with this and the lambda solution.
The difference is remarkable.....

```
void Main()
{
    string str = "RamaSubbaReddyabcdaacacakkkoooahgafffgahgghsa";
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        int count = CountChar(str, 'a');
     }   
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Using IndexOf:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());  
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        int countA = str.Count(r => r == 'a');
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Using Count:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
}
```

The first loop ends in 1160 milliseconds and the second one in 6200 milliseconds.
Can someone spot if there are problems in this measurements?

Comment: Well this is MUCH better than splitting a string at the char and building an array of strings. Not sure if it is more performant than the LINQ solutions proposed, but with these strings it is a real micro difference

Comment: This is actually potentially faster, since there is no lambda callback on each iteration. So that will save you *at least* one-billionth of a second. Maybe even two!

Comment: (Regarding your edit) Yeah, that's about what I would've expected. Recusion/Lambdas are useful in that they simplify the program conceptually, but they certainly don't do you any performance favors. They do open up the way towards parallel solutions though....