# Number of occurrences of a character in a string and their positions

Tags: c#, string, search

```
Console.WriteLine("Insert the character you are searching for: ");
CharacterSearch = Console.ReadLine();
var count = file.Where(x => x == CharacterSearch).Count();
```

So what I am trying to do is to read text from the variable `file` and then search for a specific character in the string that is entered from the keyboard. So the searched character would be `CharacterSearch`.

I also want to check for their positions not just the number of occurrences.

Comment: forgot to say that this does not show the number of aparitions because i get the error "Operator == cannot be used for Strings or Char".

Comment: First off [How would you count occurrences of a string within a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string)

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question.

Comment: Just get the first character from the input string, or do a ReadKey instead of a ReadLine

Answer (score 1):

This is **very inefficient**, but it's an option is the files are small.

```
CharacterSearch = Console.ReadKey();
var count = File.ReadLines(pathToFile)
    .Select((c, i) => new { Character = c, Index = i })
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => x.Character == CharacterSearch);
```

Comment: i get the error Char does not contain a definition of KeyChar

Comment: Now i get the error : System.IO.StreamReader does not contain a definition of select.Keep in mind im trying to search through a text file.:(

Comment: @user2524603, please see my edit, and get rid of that `StreamReader`.

Comment: Now  i get no errors but the program just does nothing after this point.

Comment: This is the file code! might have something to do with it.
            Console.WriteLine(Extra);
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(PathS);
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                counter++;
            }

Comment: @user2524603, well you've got to do something with the results. It's a `List<T>` where `T` is the anonymous type created there.

Comment: @user2524603, get *rid of the `StreamReader`!* The `File.ReadLines` does *all the work.*

Answer (score 1):

Why not **simply** use this method? (Are you looking for a complicated one?)

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
{
    if (file[i]==CharacterSearch)
    {
        indexes.Add(i);    
    }
}

int count = indexes.Count;
```

Comment: file[i] == CharacterSearch line has the same error i had before that operator == cannot be used for Char and String

Comment: @user2524603 Because you need `char CharacterSearch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;`

Answer (score 0):

Inefficient but can be applied if file is small.

```
public static int CharCount(string input,char c)
{
    var charCount=input.GroupBy(a => a).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
    if (charCount.ContainsKey(c))
        return charCount[c];
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to do the search over an over in the same string, i think it is better maintain a mapping. Again considerable only for a small file.

```
 public static Dictionary<char, int> CharCountMapping(string input)
{
    return input.GroupBy(a => a).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
}
```