# Error when counting a specific word in a string with Regex.Matches

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to find a method to count a specific word in a string, and I found this.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("hi, hi, everybody.", ",");
int cnt = matches.Count;
Console.WriteLine(cnt);
```

It worked fine, and the result shows 2.
But when I change "," to ".", it shows 18, not the expected 1. Why?

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("hi, hi, everybody.", ".");
```

and when I change "," to "(", it shows me an error!
the error reads:

```
SYSTEM.ARGUMENTEXCEPTION - THERE ARE TOO MANY (...
```

I don't understand why this is happening

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("hi( hi( everybody.", "(");
```

Other cases seem to work fine but I need to count "(".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first instance, with the `.`, is using a special character which has a different meaning in regular expressions. It is matching ALL of the characters you have; hence you getting a result of 18.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

To match an actual "." character, you'll need to "escape" it so that it is read as a full-stop and not a special character.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("hi, hi, everybody.", "\.");
```

The same exists for the `(` character. It's a special character that has a different meaning in terms of regular expressions and you will need to escape it.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("hi( hi( everybody.", "\(");
```

Looks like you're new to regular expressions so I'd suggest reading, the link I posted above is a good start.

HOWEVER!

If you are looking to just count ocurences in a string, you don't need regex.

[How would you count occurrences of a string within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string/541994#541994)

If you're using .NET 3.5 you can do this in a one-liner with LINQ:

```
int cnt = source.Count(f => f == '(');
```

If you don't want to use LINQ you can do it with:

```
int cnt = source.Split('(').Length - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter represents a pattern, not necessarily just a character to search for in your string, and the `(` by itself is an invalid pattern.

You don't need Regex to count occurrences of a character. Just use LINQ's [`Count()`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/count):

```
var input = "hi( hi( everybody.";

var occurrences = input.Count(x => x == '(');  // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`(` character is a special character which means start of a [group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you need to use `(` as literal you need to escape it with `\(`. That should solve your problem.