# Count occurences of a string pattern, in a string using Linq

Tags: c#, string, linq

Im working to correctly map links on websites.

I need to be able to count how often `../` occurs in a string. **At this moment I have a function that loops through the string and counts, while this works, im looking for a Linq solution**.

I know that I can count with a single character like this

```
 int count = Href.Count(f => f == '/');
```

But, can I, by using `LINQ` , count how often the pattern `../` occurs? Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to use LINQ, this seems like a job for a regex?

Comment: I have a hammer. I need to drive this screw into the wall. How do I hit it with the hammer?

Comment: Fundementally if you use LINQ 'directly' on a string you're using LINQ on an IEnumerable<char>, It will be easier NOT to use LINQ as ALL you can really get out of LINQ is an index enumeration.

I'd look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string

Comment: Please don't call a __'string'__ like "../" a __'pattern'__! A pattern would be "*.bmp"  or the like..

Comment: RegEx will be the fastest with String.Replace coming in 2nd. LINQ is slow and tends to crash on large data.. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string) - Please note: On that post almost __all answers, including the accepted one are wrong!__ Ramos has got it right, though.. And the OP in his own question..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this extension method:

```
public static int ContainsCount(this string input, string subString, bool countIntersecting = true, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
{
    int occurences = 0;
    int step = countIntersecting ? 1 : subString.Length;
    int index = -step;
    while ((index = input.IndexOf(subString, index + step, comparison)) >= 0)
        occurences++;
    return occurences;
}
```

which returns the number of sub-strings in a given string with pure string-methods:

```
int count = Href.ContainsCount("../");
```

[`String`-methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) are superior to other methods which use LINQ or regex in terms of efficiency.

This method supports counting intersecting sub-strings(default) and non-overlapping sub-strings.

This shows the difference:

```
string str = "ottotto";
int count = str.ContainsCount("otto");      // 2
count = str.ContainsCount("otto", false);   // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that nicely with Regex

```
var dotdotslash=new Regex(@"\.\./");
string test="../../bla/../";
int count=dotdotslash.Matches(test).Count;
```

↓

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but it's very awkward, it will be slow, and it will be hard to read. Don't use it.

[How would you count occurrences of a string within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string)

```
src.Select((c, i) => src.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.StartsWith(target))
```

Alternatively, this looks pretty beautiful:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> IndexOfAll(this string input, string value){
        var currentIndex = 0;

        while((currentIndex = input.IndexOf(value, currentIndex)) != -1)
            yield return currentIndex++;
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
"TESTHATEST"
    .IndexOfAll("TEST")
    .Count()
    .Dump();
```

Comment: @SimonWhitehead; what do you mea by that? The above LINQ seems faulty because <character>.Contains("string") doesn't make sense.

Comment: The above link is one of the strangest posts I have seen on SO ever..! Ridiculous scores and almost all answers wrong (in that they only can count characters, not substrings.. And besides RegEx the OP has a funny solution, that beats the rest by doing a String.Replace..!

Answer (score 0):

*Regular expression* (see *Dmitry Ledentsov's answer*) is much better here; however Linq is also possible:

```
  String source = @"abc../def../";

  // 2
  int result = source
    .Where((item, index) => source.Substring(index).StartsWith(@"../"))
    .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do it in a really LINQy (and awkward :) ) way like this:

```
private static int CountPatternAppearancesInString(string str, string pattern)
{
    var count = str
        .Select(
            (_, index) =>
                index < str.Length - pattern.Length + 1 &&
                str.Skip(index)
                    .Take(pattern.Length)
                    .Zip(pattern, (strChar, patternChar) => strChar == patternChar)
                    .All(areEqual => areEqual))
        .Count(isMatch => isMatch);

    return count;
}
```

Or, using some of the String-provided methods:

```
private static int CountPatternAppearancesInString(string str, string pattern)
{
    var count = str
        .Select(
            (_, index) =>
                index < str.Length - pattern.Length + 1 &&
                str.IndexOf(pattern, index, pattern.Length) >= 0)
        .Count(isMatch => isMatch);

    return count;
}
```

But, as already said, it is suboptimal and serves for illustration purpose only.