# The fastest way to count string occurences in another string in c#

Tags: c#

I have to count string occurences in one very loooong string (about 30mb in plain text)
I use the following code for now:
`int count = new Regex(Regex.Escape(stringThatIamLookingFor)).Matches(stringToSearchIn).Count;`
but is is too slow. It takes about 3 minutes on i7 and 16gb ram.
The example data is:

```
43.996442,-31.768039
43.996432,-31.768039
43.996432,-31.768049
43.996422,-31.768049
43.996422,-31.768059
```

I want to count (for example) `.7`
Is there faster way than regeex?

## ok, solved

The fastest function so far is: (I need to check only two chars.)

```
public int countOccurences2(string source, char charOne, char charTwo)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<=source.Length-1; i=i+2)
            if (source[i] == charOne && source[i + 1] == charTwo) { count++; }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: How long does it take to convert the string into a byte array and just looking for the correct two numbers with a simple for loop? Sometimes the low tech method isn't the worst.

Comment: [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you count occurrences of a string within a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string)

Comment: please let us know how well perform each solution. For science! :D

Comment: HOLY CRAP, Simone Riboldi's answer is about 10 times faster than regex.

Comment: original solution is of Richard Watson, see the question in my answer ;) You should say thank to him and not me ;)

Comment: @Jens: The last time I checked that (__terrible! terrible!__) post, RegEx won for truely large needles and haystacks.

Comment: @pythoner does the solution provide the same results too?

Comment: Yes, but still too slow in really huge strings:c

Comment: try with int count = source.Split(char[] source).Length - 1;

Comment: Since you are doing test anyway, the method posted in the original question using replace was amazingly fast, so you may want to give it a spin as well..

Answer (score 3):

from this question:
[How would you count occurrences of a string within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string)

the following code seems the most performing:

```
int count = 0, n = 0;

if(substring != "")
{
    while ((n = source.IndexOf(substring, n, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)) != -1)
    {
        n += substring.Length;
        ++count;
    }
}
```

solution provided by Richard Watson in the mentioned question

Comment: Note that the accepted answer and actually most answers are plain wrong as they count characters; also note that any Linq solution breaks down for large strings! This is the worst example of vote gauging going wrong I have ever seen on SO

Comment: but this one seems a good solution accordingly to OP too (or at least I hope so!)

Comment: Yes, probably because the needle is so short. I did tests last year and when both needle and haystack grow regex finally wins.

Comment: @TaW good to know, very good to know! We always need this kind of function and it is really usefull to know the weakness of each approach.

Comment: I might also add that due to Unicode considerations, any comparison based on simple byte comparisons will give the incorrect answer on some data, so using a method like this that respects Unicode is a definite plus.

Comment: I think this answer is (arguably) wrong due to the "n += substring.Length" line - if you search for "abca" in the string "abcabca" then it will only return 1 when (arguably) it should return 2.