# Search string for string sequence

Tags: c++

What is the most efficient way to count a number of occurrences of a substring in another string in C++? For example, I have a very huge string like

```
"GQWHIWQGHWGGEEEGQIHIGWHIQWGHIEEEGPHIQPIWGHQPWGPHEEEGQIHWPWGQHPQWGEEE"
```

and I want to count how often `"EEE"` occurs.

I could go step by step in a for loop and check every letter if it's an E and if so, count them and if there are 3 `e`s, increment a counter, but I guess there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Maybe a string function? I just wasn't able to find or google a suitable one.

I am searching for a clean C++11 solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string

Comment: The referenced question is about C#, not C++.

Comment: its not a dublicate, the question you postet is a c# question, i want a c++ solution. You cannot compare a c# solution wirh a c++ solution.

Comment: Also a C solution is not a c++ solution

Comment: Sure it is.  The referenced question and answer discuss generic searching algorithms.  They can be implemented in C++.

Comment: What about count function from STL http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/ ?

Comment: @Alex - What you are looking for is an algorithm that searches the string the fastest.  If you took the time to actually read the link I gave, it gives you the algorithms used to search strings.  Having said that, any C++ implementation will practically mimic, if not outright duplicate the same code the C solution gives.  There aren't that many different ways to write a Boyer-Moore (for example) search.  One thing that you can copy directly from C are *algorithmic approaches*.  This is an example where looking at C code to implement something in C++ won't kill your program or design.

Comment: // count algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::count
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <string>
int main ( ) {
 // counting elements in array:
 std::string test ( "iqwhhigpÉEEpgihfqwhgwqEEEgjowqogwqoEEEgwqojügwjqojoEEE" );
 int mycount = std::count ( test.begin(), test.end(), "EEE" );
 std::cout << "10 appears " << mycount << " times.\n";


 std::cout << "EEE appears " << mycount << " times.\n";
 system ( "pause" );
 return 0;
}
Where is the mistake in the count function? Throws error:

Comment: error C2446: '==': Keine Konvertierung von 'const char *' in 'int'

Comment: There is a solution at RosetaCode http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring#C.2B.2B

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pattern-searching-set-7-boyer-moore-algorithm-bad-character-heuristic/

Booyer seems to be the wrong thing if i do not understand it wrong.
I want to find out how often a string exists in another string, not where one

@zser7610 
Year, this solution looks pretty nice, but i am not sure about the performance of using str.find

Comment: @Alex Your program does not work because std::count counts occurrences of an individual container element in a container. So it can be used to count characters in a string, not substrings in a string. I was wrong to suggest it.

Comment: @Alex - Look at the link you posted -- it starts out with a program that prints all occurrences.  Come on, how hard would it be to take that code at RosetaCode and change it to just stick a counter variable that increments every time a string is found?

Comment: @Alex Look at the `offset` variable. It goes through the string only once. Therefore it is linear in the length of the string searched in. (And the string searched for). O(m+n) If you are ok with "non-overlapping occurrences", then the RosetaCode solution is the best you can get.

Comment: Reasonable overview of existing string search algorithms is on WIkipedia, #Finite_state_automaton_based_search

Comment: How many times does "eee" exist in "eeee"? Once, or twice?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a fast and efficent solution, take a look at [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) - it takes only O(N+M) to search.
If you want something in STL style, then take a look at [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)