# C#. How to Find a small string inside bigger string?

Tags: c#, string

I have an input string like this:

> Tshirt39Tshirt39Tshirt15Jean39Jean52Jean52Jean52

And then I want to have an output:

> Tshirt39:2 Unit(s)
>   Tshirt15:1 Unit(s)
>   Jean39:1 Unit(s)
>   Jean52:3 Unit(s)

Or

> Tshirt:15+39+39
>   Jean:39+52+52+52"

This my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("In put data:\n");
string total = Console.ReadLine();
// In put to string total: "Tshirt39Tshirt39Tshirt15Jean39Jean52Jean52Jean52"
string b = "Tshirt39" ;
int icount=0;

for (int i=0;i<total.Length;i++)
{
   if ( total.Contains(b));
   {
       icount+=1;
   }
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Tshirt39:{0} Unit(s)",icount);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I want result of ouput "Tshirt" is: 2 :(
[image]

Comment: Please attempt to solve the problem yourself, and post the code here so we can help you.  If you are not sure where to start, I suggest looking into the String.Contains() method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx and the String.Split() method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx

Comment: You can't solve the problem but at least you can format the code and post a proper question right?

Comment: Thanks man, i tried use loop For and String.Contains() method but it just show "Tshirt39" 1 time :( not 2 times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you count occurrences of a string within a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string)

Comment: Thanks man, I'm studying REGEX :3 @DIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *regular expressions* (to extract goods) and *Linq* (to combine the goods into proper representation):

```
  String source = "Tshirt39Tshirt39Tshirt15Jean39Jean52Jean52Jean52";

  var result = Regex
    .Matches(source, "(?<name>[A-Z][a-z]+)(?<size>[0-9]+)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .GroupBy(value => value)
    .Select(chunk => String.Format("{0}:{1} Unit(s)", 
       chunk.Key, chunk.Count()));

  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

Test:

```
  // Tshirt39:2 Unit(s)
  // Tshirt15:1 Unit(s)
  // Jean39:1 Unit(s)
  // Jean52:3 Unit(s)
  Console.Write(report);
```

If you want second type representation:

```
  var result = Regex
    .Matches(source, "(?<name>[A-Z][a-z]+)(?<size>[0-9]+)") // same regex
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => new {
      name = match.Groups["name"].Value,
      size = int.Parse(match.Groups["size"].Value),
    })
    .GroupBy(value => value.name)
    .Select(chunk => String.Format("{0}: {1}", 
       chunk.Key, String.Join(" + ", chunk.Select(item => item.size))));

  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

Test:

```
  // Tshirt: 39 + 39 + 15
  // Jean: 39 + 52 + 52 + 52
  Console.Write(report);
```

Comment: Thanks your support man :D look it seen not like C# langguage ( or use SQL sever) :( or my level is low

Comment: @Hung Nguyen: *Linq* is quite typical feature of C#, IMHO, it's worth being studied.