# VB program that counts the number of times a specific word occurs in a sentence

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have recently started with Visual Basic so I am not very familiar with it. I am new to computing so bear with me! I am attempting to make a form program that counts a specific word in a sentence. I haven't got very far with it as you can see from my code. All I have got it to do is tell me if the two text boxes match. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with a solution! Many thanks.

code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If Word.Text = Sentence.Text Then
            Counter1.Text = Counter + 1
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB.NET and C# use the same underlying object model, so you can adapt an [exising C# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string).

Here's how your sub would look:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If Word.Text.Length = 0 Then
        counter = 0
    Else
        counter = ( Sentence.Text.Length - Sentence.Text.Replace(Word.Text,"").Length ) / Word.Text.Length
    End If
    Counter1.Text = counter
End Sub
```

This method counts all ocurrences in one go, without a loop, so you don't need an incrementor.

As @romulus001 mentions, the length of `Word.Text` could be zero, so this should be checked before dividing by it. If the length of `Word.Text` is zero, then the count you want is probably zero since you are literally looking for nothing.

Comment: What if the Word field is empty? You cannot divide by 0

Comment: Thanks very much, really appreciate it

Comment: No problem, glad we could help.

Comment: is there a way  that i could change this sub so that the program outputs the position of the word in the sentence. for example: if the sentence is "dog cat horse cat" and the word was cat, it would output 2,4 because thats where it occurs in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it must be case sensitive or not, but you can use one of these codes :

1)

```
Counter = Sentence.Text.split(Word.Text).Length - 1 'if the search is case sensitive
```

2)

```
Counter = Sentence.Text.toUpper.split(Word.Text.toUpper).Length - 1 'if the search is NOT case sensitive`
```

then:

```
Counter1.Text = Counter
```