# LINQ that contains symbol only once

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Need your help: I have Datable that has datarows like :

```
test1
test1:1
test1:1:1
test1:2
```

I need to select only rows that contain ":" only once.
Result should be like :
test1:1 
test1:2

Any ideas how to make it ??
I stuck after :

```
var result = dTable.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Name").Contains(":"));
```

,where "Name" is a column Name.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = dTable.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Name").Count(z=>z==':')==1);
```

or

```
var result = dTable.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Name").Where(z=>z==':').Count()==1);
```

or

```
var result = dTable.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Name").IndexOf(':') == dr.Field<string>("Name").LastIndexOf(':') && dr.Field<string>("Name").Contains(":"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the content of the Field to a Char array and then count the number of times you get the ':'

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Name")
               .ToCharArray()
               .Count(c => c == ':') == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```cs
var result = dTable.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Name").Count(f => f == ':') == 1);
```

With LINQ, this is very easy using `x.Count()`.

If you want to do it without LINQ, try this:

```cs
var result = dTable.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Name").Split(':').Length - 1 == 1);
```

See the top answer at [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-actually-a-char-within-a-string), which has something similar. I don't usually use LINQ, so forgive me if my code doesn't work. Hope this helps!