# How to check reoccurring characters in string c#

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I am developing an email validation and wanting to check if there has is more than 1 @ symbol in the email, how do i go on about implementing this?

```
static string Check(string email)
    {
        
        if (email.Contains("@") && email.Contains("."))
        {
          // check for 2 @ symbols or more will be here

            
         return email;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Use an available regex for this(or the `MailAddress` constructor), don't reinvent the wheel. https://emailregex.com/

Comment: Maybe use `.GroupBy`? Or `.IndexOf` to find the first one and `.IndexOf` with the initial offset to see if there is another. Or use Regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you count occurrences of a string (actually a char) within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-actually-a-char-within-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should not reinvent the wheel, especially not with a complex topic like email validation. Use an [available regex](https://emailregex.com/) or the `MailAddress` constructor.

However, to answer your question, if you really need something like that (for other tasks) you could implement an extension method like this:

```
public static IList<int> AllIndexOf(this string text, string str, StringComparison comparisonType)
{
    IList<int> allIndexOf = new List<int>();
    int index = text.IndexOf(str, comparisonType);
    while(index != -1)
    {
        allIndexOf.Add(index);
        index = text.IndexOf(str, index + 1, comparisonType);
    }
    return allIndexOf;
}
```

with this it's easy:

```
if(email.AllIndexOf("@", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count > 1)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh that site is a nice find!