# Have quesion while using C# string Substring method

Tags: c#, string

Today I'm trying to fix some problem but i can't understand why return this Ans to me.

```
string text = "<Design><Code>"

var Ans = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(">"));
```

I can't understand why Ans will return `"<Design"` this to me.
I think the `"<Design>"`  <-- this Ans was correct.

Comment: `text.IndexOf(">")` will return 7 here. so `<Design` is right - second argument to `Substring()` is number of characters to copy.

Comment: `var Ans = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(">") + 1);`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `IndexOf` is going to return the zero-based index. `text.Substring()` is wanting the **length** as an argument, or the one-based number of characters in the string.

If I index, starting at zero, under your input:

```
<Design><Code>
01234567
```

You're passing 7 as the number of characters. If I count (starting at ONE) under your input:

```
<Design><Code>
1234567
```

You can see that the first seven characters are `<Design`

Comment: do you have any solution can 
out put the ans was 
`ans1 = "<Design>"
ans2 = "<Code>"`

and using for loop

Comment: @Howard: `var items = Regex.Matches(text, @"\<[^>]*\>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();`

Comment: @Howard [Count how many `>` you have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541994/5171120) first, then you can do a `for` loop for each character you've got. The loop would get the index, get the substring, then [remove the substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-6.0) with `text = text.Remove()` and the same arguments you're passing to `Substring()`. I'd keep the `ans` as a List so you can `.Add()` answers dynamically.