# Java / Android regex question

Tags: java, regex

I would like to create a regex in Java / Android which truncates a string after, or actually at, the third comma. Is this possible? Any suggestions to get me started on this?

Comment: Suggestions to get you started on this? [Learn regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: @Martihno - I know...I know. I just do them infrequently enough that I always kind of start from scratch. Posting a question on SO gives me a bit of motivation to get going on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

Alternatives: [`String#split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) your string or use a [`StringTokenizer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: Using split or StringTokenizer would force him to concatenate the results. Not very elegant imo.

Comment: Sure, but I don't know what he actually wants to achieve or do with the result (thus only 'alternatives'). Just wanted give some suggestions as stated in his answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. All the answers were great, but since regular expressions look like swears to me, I went with a nice little split and a loop. .

Comment: Did you look at my two non-regex solutions? They don't require any loops.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure regular expressions would be my first approach here. Below are my alternatives anyway.

- **Using regular expressions** ([ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/fUgQZ))

  ```
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*?,.*?,.*?),").matcher(str);
  if (m.find())
      str = m.group(1);
  ```
- **Using `indexOf` / `substring`** ([ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/8gWf8))

  ```
  str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(',',
                         str.indexOf(',',
                         str.indexOf(',') + 1) + 1));
  ```

- **Using [`nthOccurrence`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string/3976656#3976656)** ([ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/Ohqzq))

  ```
  str = str.substring(0, nthOccurrence(str, ',', 2));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Translate `s/([^,]*,){3}.+/\1/` into Java regex-ese to truncate after the third comma, `s/([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*),.+/\1/` to have the truncated portion include the third comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
int comma = -1;
int n = 0;
do {
    comma = str.indexOf(',', comma + 1);
} while (comma >= 0 && ++n < 3);
if (comma > 0) {
    str = str.substring(0, comma);
} else {
    // third comma not found
}
```