# Java split string on third comma

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string that I need to be split into 2. I want to do this by splitting at exactly the third comma.

How do I do this?

**Edit**

A sample string is :

```
from:09/26/2011,type:all,to:09/26/2011,field1:emp_id,option1:=,text:1234
```

The string will keep the same format - I want everything before field in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're simply interested in splitting the string at the index of the third comma, I'd probably do something like this:

```
String s = "from:09/26/2011,type:all,to:09/26/2011,field1:emp_id,option1:=,text:1234";

int i = s.indexOf(',', 1 + s.indexOf(',', 1 + s.indexOf(',')));

String firstPart = s.substring(0, i);
String secondPart = s.substring(i+1);

System.out.println(firstPart);
System.out.println(secondPart);
```

**Output:**

```
from:09/26/2011,type:all,to:09/26/2011
field1:emp_id,option1:=,text:1234
```

---

**Related question:**

- [How to find nth occurrence of character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string)

Comment: quick question - would this work if I wanted to get every third comma?

Comment: Naah, then you probably want a loop of some kind. Have a look at the related question I posted. Alternatively, why don't you split on `","` and join the parts you want grouped together.

Answer (score 2):

a naive implementation

```
public static String[] split(String s)
{
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        index = s.indexOf(",", index+1);

    return new String[] {
            s.substring(0, index),
            s.substring(index+1)
    };
}
```

This does no bounds checking and will throw all sorts of lovely exceptions if not given input as expected.   Given `"ABCD,EFG,HIJK,LMNOP,QRSTU"` returns `["ABCD,EFG,HIJK","LMNOP,QRSTU"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*),(.*)$
```

The result is then in the two captures (1 and 2), not including the third comma.

Comment: That just returned my full string. I have edited the above with a sample string

Comment: @pm13, yes it does match the full string, but the captures (as I wrote) contain the two distinct parts.