# Split Paragraphs Java: i want first 50 words in one variable from string

Tags: java

I have

```
String explanation = "The image-search feature will start rolling out in the next few days, said Johanna Wright, a Google search director. "Every picture has a story, and we want to help you discover that story she said.";
```

there are total number of words are 300

In Java, how do I get the first 50 words from the string?

Comment: You want the first 50 words, or the first 50 characters?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you see anything in the JavaDocs for the `String` class you think might help?

Comment: there are 35 words and 199 characters in the string you show in your example.  neither 35 nor 199 equals 300.

Comment: i am wan first 50 words in string

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, perfect explanation: http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/show-the-first-n-and-last-n-words-232

Comment: Please add an answer or update the link above as it is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of a word, this may do for you:

Search for the 50:th space character, and then extract the substring from 0 to that index.

Here is some example code for you:

```
public static int nthOccurrence(String str, char c, int n) {
    int pos = str.indexOf(c, 0);
    while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1)
        pos = str.indexOf(c, pos+1);
    return pos;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";

    int numWords = 4;
    int i = nthOccurrence(text, ' ', numWords - 1);
    String intro = i == -1 ? text : text.substring(0, i);

    System.out.println(intro); // prints "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
}
```

**Related question:**

- [How to find nth occurrence of character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string)

Comment: This is not what he wants, he wants to count words, not occurrences of some character.

Comment: Assuming space character separates words, that's roughly the same thing.

Comment: @user935988 In that case you should accept this answer by clicking the big check mark (✓) on the left side of it.

Answer (score 0):

Split the incoming data with a regex, bounds check, then rebuild the first 50 words.

```
String[] words = data.split(" ");
String firstFifty = "";
int max = words.length;
if (max > 50) 
  max = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
  firstFifty += words[i] + " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (If you want the first 50 words):

```
String explanation="The image-search feature will start rolling out in the next few days, said Johanna Wright, a Google search director. "Every picture has a story, and we want to help you discover that story she said."

String[] words = explanation.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(50, words.length); i++)
{
 sb.append(words[i] + " ");  
}
System.out.println("The first 50 words are: " + sb.toString());
```

Or something like this if you want the first 50 characters:

```
String explanation="The image-search feature will start rolling out in the next few days, said Johanna Wright, a Google search director. "Every picture has a story, and we want to help you discover that story she said."

String truncated = explanation.subString(0, Math.min(49, explanation.length()));
```