# Regex to display a string from the second last occurence of a character

Tags: regex, string

Need an Regex to display a string from the second last occurence of a character

**Example: "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/"**

In this case, if I ask for 2nd occurrence of slash (/) from last , it appears before folder4, and I expect to return substring from 2nd last occurrence of a character.

i.e the return string should be **folder4/**

Comment: [Click for answer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: possible duplicate
[how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Look for the last occurence of your token
- Take the result `- 1` as parameter for a second `lastIndexOf()`
- Take this result as param for `substring()`

Like so:

```
final String example = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/";
final String result  = example.substring(example.lastIndexOf('/', example.lastIndexOf('/') - 1), example.length() - 1);

System.out.printf("%s\n", result);
```

Or a bit more readable

```
final String example = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/";
int pos;

pos = example.lastIndexOf('/');
pos = example.lastIndexOf('/', pos - 1);
result = example.substring(pos, example.length - 1);

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: exactly the one i need. Thanks for your immediate answer.

Answer (score 2):

In php:

```
$str = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/";
$str = preg_replace('#^.*/([^/]+/[^/]*)$#', "$1", $str);
```

In perl:

```
$str = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/";
$str =~ s#^.*/([^/]+/[^/]*)$#$1#;
```

Comment: This was very useful, thanks! For the RAW regex, if anybody else is gonna use this, ignore the hashtags - these are php-specific

Answer (score 0):

in Java:

```
    String fileName = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/";
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(fileName);
    while(m.find())
    {
        arr.add(m.group(1));            
    }       
    return arr.get(arr.size()-2);
```

where 2  is  occurrence.  This  allows you to  have  everything  grouped  so  you  can  handle  also  other  groups.