# How to find the n-th occurrence of a separator in a string?

Tags: java, io

```
123,one,two,three,for,five,six
```

How could I best extract the word after the 3rd occurrence of the `,` separator? (which would be `three` in my example.

Probably I'm not the first one doing this and there might be an apache or guava library that provides a static method for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string

Comment: If you're after *three* rather than the position of the separator char, you would just do .split(",")[3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You van simply use .split(",")[3]

Comment: OK that's probably the easiest solution here.