# Reading a string in java until certain character matched 3rd time

Tags: java

Im reading a file which contains  Urls like  (http://www.espncricinfo.com/netstorage/817215.json?xhr=1) , How  to get the  string like (http://www.espncricinfo.com/) before 3rd ('/').

Comment: have u considered using url.getHost() instead?

Comment: Take a look at this question about getting the [nth index of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string). If you implement that its simple to use in in conjunction with `substring()`.

Comment: Thanks nafas it is working . and other comments are also valid for me and i will also trying to  solve it using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way: make use of `RegEx`,

```
    String link = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/netstorage/817215.json?xhr=1";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((https?://)[^/]+/?)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(link);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

better way: Make use of `URL` package:

```
    URL url = new URL(link);
    System.out.println(url.getHost());
```

Comment: I want to try it but answered  ,good

Comment: @sharief does ur file contain other stuff?

Comment: @sharief try it now, it should only pick urls starting with http:// or https://

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way seems to be creating the [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) object and getting the host name from it

```
String url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/netstorage/817215.json?xhr=1";
URL u = new URL(url);
System.out.println(u.getHost());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java.net.URL:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.espncricinfo.com/netstorage/817215.json?xhr=1");
String before_3rd = url.getProtocol() +"://" + url.getHost() + url.getPort();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `URI` method `resolve`:

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://www.espncricinfo.com/netstorage/817215.json?xhr=1&a=b");
String result = uri.resolve("/").toString();
```

This method basically uses your original URI as the basis to calculating a similar URI with a different path. By giving it the path `"/"` it means you will get back the original base URI (including user info or port if they were there). Printing the result above will give:

```
http://www.espncricinfo.com/
```

And if your original URL was:

```
http://user:pass@www.espncricinfo.com:8080/netstorage/817215.json?xhr=1
```

The result would be:

```
http://user:pass@www.espncricinfo.com:8080/
```