# How to abbreviate string at the middle without cutting words

Tags: java, string

I am using `StringUtils.abbreviateMiddle(string, middle, targetLength);` to abbreviate string in the middle but using this method cuts off the word. Is there a way such that it will only cut off string at the space nearest to the middle position of the string?

```
public static String shortenStringMiddle(String string, String middle, int targetLength) {
    targetLength = Math.abs(targetLength);

    if (string != null && string.length() > targetLength) {

        return StringUtils.abbreviateMiddle(string, middle, targetLength);
    }
    else {
        return string;
    }
}
```

Input if applied to this text:

> Disease Control in Fish and Shrimp Aquaculture in Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques: Proceedings of the SEAFDEC-OIE Seminar-Workshop on Disease Control in Fish and Shrimp Aquaculture in Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques, 4-6 December 2001, Iloilo City, Philippines

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.abbreviateMiddle("Disease Control in Fish and Shrimp Aquaculture in Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques: Proceedings of the SEAFDEC-OIE Seminar-Workshop on Disease Control in Fish and Shrimp Aquaculture in Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques, 4-6 December 2001, Iloilo City, Philippines", " &#8230; ", 220));
```

Output:

> Disease Control in Fish and Shrimp Aquaculture in Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques: **Procee** … **aculture** in Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques, 4-6 December 2001, Iloilo City, Philippines

The word Proceedings was cut off to **Procee** and Aquaculture to **aculture**

My ideal output would be:

> Disease Control in Fish and Shrimp Aquaculture in Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques: Proceedings … Aquaculture in Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques, 4-6 December 2001, Iloilo City, Philippines

I've searched here in SO and similar questions only relates to abbreviate string adding an ellipsis at the end.

Comment: Why don't you use `indexOf(String)` to find the correct locations? I'm confused on the problem you are having, not to mention, you don't show us your `abbreviateMiddle` method

Comment: @VinceEmigh The `abbreviateMiddle` method is taken from Apache Commons `StringUtils`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yeah, I realized shortly after. But it would be nice to include that info, as not everyone uses commons (or even simply use the fully qualified name in the code)

Comment: What is your input for `string`, `middle` and `targetlength`?

Comment: @M.Shaw, my input for `string` is in the post above (See **Input if applied to this text:**). `middle` is `" &#8230; "` which is an ellipsis, and `targetlength` is `220`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another implementation based on a regular expression:

```
public static String abbreviateMiddle(String input, String middle, int length) {
    if (input != null && input.length() > length) {
        int half = (length - middle.length()) / 2;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
                "^(.{" + half + ",}?)" + "\\b.*\\b" + "(.{" + half + ",}?)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return matcher.group(1) + middle + matcher.group(2);
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

With your example text, the following call

```
System.out.println(abbreviateMiddle(exampleText, " ... ", 220));
```

will produce

> Disease Control in Fish and Shrimp Aquaculture in Southeast Asia -
>   Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques: Proceedings ... Aquaculture in
>   Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques, 4-6 December
>   2001, Iloilo City, Philippines

Comment: Hi, I'm just curious, is there an advantage of using the code above from your other answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a rough shot at it. Obviously you could implement cleaner fallback methods for cases where the string doesn't contain sufficient spaces etc., but as a base to start from, it should do just fine.

```
public static String abbreviateMiddle(String input, String middle, int targetLength) {
    if (input == null || input.length() <= targetLength) {
        return input;
    }

    int inputLength = input.length();
    int halfTargetLength = (targetLength - middle.length()) / 2;

    int startLastSpace = input.substring(0, halfTargetLength).lastIndexOf(" ");
    int endFirstSpace = input.indexOf(" ", inputLength - halfTargetLength);

    if (startLastSpace != -1 || endFirstSpace != -1) {
        return input.substring(0, startLastSpace)
                + middle
                + input.substring(endFirstSpace + 1, inputLength);
    }

    return input;
}
```

With your example text, the following call

```
System.out.println(abbreviateMiddle(exampleText, " ... ", 240));
```

will return

> Disease Control in Fish and Shrimp Aquaculture in Southeast Asia -
>   Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques: Proceedings ... Aquaculture in
>   Southeast Asia - Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques, 4-6 December
>   2001, Iloilo City, Philippines

Setting the `targetLength` to 220 will return

> Disease Control in Fish and Shrimp Aquaculture in Southeast Asia -
>   Diagnosis and Husbandry Techniques: ... in Southeast Asia - Diagnosis
>   and Husbandry Techniques, 4-6 December 2001, Iloilo City, Philippines

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public String abbreviateMiddle(String string, String middle, int targetLength) {
    String[] ssplit = string.split(" ");
    String first = "";
    String second = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ssplit.length; i++) {
        if (first.length() < targetLength / 2) {
            first += ssplit[i] + " ";
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = ssplit.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (second.length() < targetLength / 2) {
            second = ssplit[i] + " " + second;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return first + middle + second;
}
```

If you want the result string to be maximum length but strictly less than targetLength (rather than the above code which returns the minimum string that has a length GREATER than targetLength), use

```
if (first.length() + ssplit[i].length() < targetLength /2)
```

and

```
if (second.length() + ssplit[i].length() < targetLength / 2)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Vince's comment, you could use indexOf(" ") since a space will represent the end of a word (and thus you will not cut off a word).  I would look through, [find the number of instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string) of " " in your input, then estimate how many words to put on either end in order to be at or below your char limit (from the targetLength in your method) and then [get the substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976656/2574577) after and below your elected instances of " ".  I don't know java so I can't write that code for you though, sorry.