# How to get indexOf element which isn't the first

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

#### Assumed

```
ArrayList<Integer> list =  Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,8,9});
```

#### Find second occurence

I want to get the *index of* the **second** finding of the (multiple) contained element "1" but `list.indexOf(1)` will always return `0` (as it's the first finding).

#### Performance

I want to do this without using loops like `for` or `while`.
Since I need it for a game, using loops wouldn't be efficient at all.

EDIT: Is there any way to get "indexOf" some element **without iterator** ?

Comment: `indexOf` also iterates over the list.

Comment: Well guess ill habe to change my question now

Comment: use `subList` and then `indexOf` (but not more efficient, but readable IMO)

Comment: You can use lastIndexOf

Comment: Yeah but lets say the array is [1,2,3,1,4,1] and i would like to get the middle one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this without iterating.
`indexOf` iterates, for example.

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Same is valid for `lastIndexOf`.
As you can see no `Iterator<Integer>` is used at all, if that is what worries you.

And, btw, **this isn't a performance concern**.
Do you have arrays with millions of elements? If you have, consider changing data structure type.

Answer (score 1):

If you are very much concerned about performance, use a `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>`. Then if your want n'th occurence of an element `m`, you can do `map.get(m).get(n)`. Your map contains elements and their corresponding indexes.

Once your map is built, the time complexity for your query would be `O(1)`

Example:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a = {1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1};
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            if(map.containsKey(a[i])){
                map.get(a[i]).add(i);
            }else{
                map.put(a[i], new ArrayList<Integer>());
                map.get(a[i]).add(i);
            }
        }

        // second index of 1. Note that index starts from 0.

        System.out.println(map.get(1).get(1));
    }
```

Result:

> 2

Answer (score 0):

```
list.indexOf(1, list.indexOf(1) + 1);
```

The *first* parameter `1` being the object to be searched.
The *second* parameter `list.indexOf(1) + 1` being the starting index for the search.

Comment: that is for `String`s not for `List`s, at least so in Java 11

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger you are correct. Although OP changed their question anyway.

Comment: You could [edit] your answer and post the link to the documentation of your mentioned method `indexOf(Object what, int where)`. I doubt it can be used on asked `List` interface or its implementation [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: Your approach is good. It could be implemented using `subList` in combination with `indexOf`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32461150) to _ArrayList : Find nth occurrence of an Integer_

Answer (score 0):

```
list.subList(list.indexOf(1) + 1, list.size()).indexOf(1)
```