# Replace only 2nd occurance in String

Tags: java, string, replace

I have following promotion String in my application.

```
String promotion = "Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol! Watch on youtube.";
```

I want to replace the second word 'Youtube' by the hyperlink, so I tried:

```
promotion = promotion.replace("youtube","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ");
```

But this replaces the first youtube, and I want the second youtube to be replaced.

I also tried:

```
promotion = promotion.replaceAll("youtube","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ");
```

But this replaces both youtubes.

What is the best approach to replace the second occurance of "youtube" by the linK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string

Comment: If it's always `youtube.` you could look for the dot. If it's aways the second `youtube` you could use a positive look-behind: `(?<=youtube.{0,999})youtube` (or if you don't want to add a maximum length of text in the look-behind use `(?<=youtube)(.*?)youtube` and re-add the group in the replacement by using the backreference `$1`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your second `"youtube"` string is also the last one, you can look for the last one and replace it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String promotion = "Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol! Watch on youtube.";
        System.out.println(promotion.replaceAll("(.*)(\\byoutube\\b)(.*)", "$1"+ "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ" + "$3" ));
    }
```

O/P :

> Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol! Watch on
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ.

If you want to replace only the second `youtube` in case you have multiple `youtube`s in your String, you can use :

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String promotion = "Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol! Watch on youtube. asas youtube";
    String stringToReplace = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ";
    System.out.println(promotion.replaceAll("(.*?\\byoutube\\b.*?)(\\byoutube\\b)(.*)", "$1"+  stringToReplace + "$3" ));
}
```

O/P :

> Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol! Watch on
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ. asas youtube