# location and repetition of characters within a string

Tags: java, string, counter

Hi biologist here with a little bit of coding background. my goal is to be able to input a string of characters and the code to be able to tell me how many times they occur and at what location in the string.
so ill be entering a string and i want the location and abundance of sq and tq within the string. with the location being the first character e.g njnsqjjfl  sq would be located at postition 4.

This is what ive come up with so far (probably very wrong)

```
string S = "...";
int counter =0;
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++){
if(s.charAt (i) == 'sq')}
counter++;})

string S = "...";
int counter =0;
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++){
if(s.charAt (i) == 'tq')}
counter++;})
```

any input will help, thankyou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find nth occurrence of character in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

So , you can have multiple occurrences of "sq" and "tq" in your code, so you can have 2 arraylists to save these two separately(or one to save them together).

```
ArrayList<Integer>sqLocation = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer>tqLocation = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i =0;i<s.length()-1;i++){
if(s.charAt(i)=='s' && s.charAt(i+1)=='q'){
  sqLocation.add(i);
  }
else if(s.charAt(i)=='t' && s.charAt(i+1)=='q'){
  tqLocation.add(i);
  }
}
System.out.println("No. of times sq occurs = "+sqLocation.size());
System.out.println("Locations ="+sqLocation);
System.out.println("No. of times tq occurs = "+tqLocation.size());
System.out.println("Locations ="+tqLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using regex. Your use case is to count occurrences and position of those occurrences. The method match returns an integer list which is position and count is size of list

Exmaple code

```
public class RegexTest {
    public static List<Integer> match(String text, String regex) {
        List<Integer> matchedPos = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(" + regex + "))").matcher(text);
        while(m.find()) {
            matchedPos.add(m.start());
        }

        return matchedPos;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(match("sadfsagsqltrtwrttqsqsqsqsqsqs", "sq"));
        System.out.println(match("sadfsagsqltrtwrttqksdfngjfngjntqtqtqtqtqtq", "tq"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a `HashMap <String, List <Integer>>`

this will hold, the String that you are looking for e.g. sq or tq, and a List of the positions that they are at.

You want to loop around using `String.indexOf`  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)

psuedocode being

```
String contents = "sadfsagsqltrtwrttqksdfngjfngjntqtqtqtqtqtq";

map.add (lookFor, new ArrayList ());  

int index = 0;
while ((index = contents.indexOf (lookFor, index)) != -1) {

  list = map.get (lookFor);
  list.add (index);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use not `charAt` but `substring` to get a part of `String`.

```
int count(String s, String target) {
    int counter = 0;
    int tlen = target.length();
    for (int i = tlen; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.substring(i - tlen, i).equals(target)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

// in some method
count("...", "sq");
count("...", "tq");
```

Comment: gives the count but not `and at what location in the string`