# Remove same subnet proxies from text file

Tags: java

I want to remove same subnet proxies from a text file.

txt.file= proxy.txt

> 19.15.15.90:61234
>
> 19.15.15.29:28010
>
> 19.15.15.80:8998
>
> 19.15.15.102:8998
>
> 25.25.24.15:8998
>
> 25.25.24.80:8998
>
> 210.192.38.25:8998
>
> 210.192.38.29:8998

I need output be

> 19.15.15.90:61234
>
> 25.25.24.15:8998
>
> 210.192.38.25:8998

It doesn't matter which proxies are removed, I just needs to keep 1 from each subnet.

subnet= first 3 numbers the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential solution<sup>1</sup> is to add all the items to a `List`, **sort the list**, and then iterate over the list checking if the first n characters are the same as the previous entry, and if not, print it.

First, we'd need to get the third index of `.` in this scenario<sup>2</sup>:

```
public static int nthIndexOf(String text, char needle, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == needle) {
            n--;
            if (n == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Then simply perform the iteration as mentioned above:

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int pos = nthIndexOf(list.get(i), '.', 3);
    if (!list.get(i).substring(0, pos).equals(list.get(i - 1).substring(0, pos))) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Oh, and just print the first entry too, as it's going to be unique, considering it hasn't been compared to anything yet.

Of course, I am just printing `System.out.println(list.get(i));`, but do whatever is necessary with it there.

[Example](https://ideone.com/6trhLk)

<sup>1</sup><sub>There may be edge cases I've missed, but that's up to you to check</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>[Credit where credit is due](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976641/6722100)</sub>

Comment: maybe sounds too stupid but, where i enter the list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist If you want to read your file into a list, read this. Or click “Example” near the bottom of my post.