# How to get the desired output in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm

If there is a given
**Inputs**
String "abcdaa/efgh/hidjk/lmno/pqrs/tuvw"  and if
int slashCounter=3,
The desired Output should be -
**Output:** abcdaa/efgh/hidjk/lmno

(Basically if slashCounter=3 only alplabets upto 4th '/' is allowed. From fourth '/'everything is ignored. Below is the few Input and Output. (There may be any number of alphabets between '/' to '/'). Below is few more inputs

**Input:**
`String aaabcd/efgh/hidjk/lmno/pqrs/tuvw`
`if int slashCounter=2`
**Output:** aaabcd/efgh/hidjk

**Input:**
`String aaabcd/efgh/hidjk/lmno/pqrs/tuvw`
`if int slashCounter=4`
**Output:** aaabcd/efgh/hidjk/lmno/pqrs

Could someone help me with the logic of this in JAVA. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find nth occurrence of character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string)

Comment: So, whats the concrete programming problem you are facing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        // till how much we want the string
        int display = sc.nextInt();
        // splits the String when "/" is encounter and then stores it in 0 index and then increases the index
        String aplhabets[] = input.split("/");
        // to add the String we want 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= display; i++) {
            sb.append(aplhabets[i]+"/");
        }
        // as we dont want the last "/" of the String we just print from 0 to string length - 1, this will remove teh last "/"
        System.out.print(sb.substring(0, sb.length()-1));
    }
```

Output:

```
aaabcd/efgh/hidjk/lmno/pqrs/tuvw
2
aaabcd/efgh/hidjk
```

`String aplhabets[] = input.split("/")` this splits the String and puts it in the  array whenever `/` is encounter.

`sb.substring(0, sb.length()-1)` this cause when we were appending String builder from he loop it's adding `/` in the end.
So in order to remove last `/` we do `sb.substring(0,sb.length-1)` where first parameter is `start index` and second index is end `index`
in `substring(int start, int end)` start in `inclusive` and  end is `exclusive`.

this is how you do the problem. Suggest you learn how to use arrays and String manipulation. this will surely benefit you.