# Remove text after a string occurrence

Tags: c#, regex, linq, string

I have a string that has the following format:

```
string sample = "A, ABC, 1, ACS,,"
```

As you can see, there are 5 occurences of the `,` character.
I need to remove **everything** after the 4th occurrence so that the final result will be:

```
string result = fx(sample, 4);
"A, ABC, 1, ACS"
```

Is it possible without a `foreach`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will there always be ,, at the end or could there be something between them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
sample.Split(',').Take(4).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + "," + s2).Substring(1);
```

This will split your string at the comma and then take only the first four parts (`"A"`, `" ABC"`, `" 1"`, `" ACS"`), concat them to one string with `Aggregate` (result: `",A, ABC, 1, ACS"`) and return everything except the first character. Result: `"A, ABC, 1, ACS"`.

Comment: String splicing in LINQ. That's hawt.

Comment: You could also replace the substring with a Trim(",".ToCharArray()) statement (removes all leading and trailing commas)

Comment: or, more concisely: Trim(',')

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.Substring method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string.replace if it is always two commas at the end

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to return the full string if there aren't enough commas to satisfy the count

```
String fx(String str, Int32 commaCount) 
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return str;
        var i = 0;
        var strLength = str.Length;
        while ((commaCount-- > 0) && (i != -1) && (i < strLength)) i = str.IndexOf(",", i + 1);
        return (i == -1 ? str : str.Substring(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `GetNthIndex` method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571716/find-nth-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string), you can use `String.Substring`:

```
public int GetNthIndex(string s, char t, int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == t)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == n)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So you could do the following:

```
string sample = "A, ABC, 1, ACS,,";
int index = GetNthIndex(sample, ',', 4);
string result = sample.Substring(0, index);
```

Comment: Wrong because I can't write a for or a foreach, I specified that in the question.

Comment: @Raffaeu Your question only said no `foreach`; `for` was not mentioned.

Comment: @Raffaeu: That downvote wasn't nice. You said "Is it possible without a `foreach`?" A `for` isn't a `foreach`.