# C# remove text after comma

Tags: c#

How can I remove specific text from a string?

for example I have this string:

```
string file = "43 , 2000-12-12 003203";
```

I need to remove the text after the comma, including comma, so I can have as a final result:

```
string file = "43";
```

thank you,

Comment: have you tried using the `Split()` method..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove text after a string occurrence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092034/remove-text-after-a-string-occurrence)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string file = "43 , 2000-12-12 003203";
string number = file.Split(',')[0].Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
string output = file.Substring(0, file.IndexOf(',')).Trim();
```

However, that might fail if the string doesn't contain a comma. To be safer:

```
int index = file.IndexOf(',');
string output = index > 0 ? file.Substring(0, index).Trim() : file;
```

You can also use `Split` as others have suggested, but [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) would provide better performance, since it stops evaluating the string after the first comma is found:

```
string output = file.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2)[0].Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly by using Split?

```
file.Split(',')[0].Trim();
```