# Substring starting at specific character count

Tags: vb.net, string, substring

How would you select the last part of a string starting at a specific character count.
For example I would like to get all text after the 3rd comma. but I get an error saying
"StartIndex cannot be less than zero."

```
Dim testString As String = "part, description, order, get this text, and this text"
Dim result As String = ""
result = testString.Substring(testString.IndexOf(",", 0, 3))
```

Comment: Do you want the text after the *third* comma, or after *the last* comma (which happens to be the same in your given sample)? If you have the input `"One, two, three, four, five and six"`, what would be your expected result? `"four, five and six"` or `"five and six"`?

Comment: yes after third comma. i sould of put a fourth one in there, i edited it for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres my two cents:

```
string.Join(",", "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee".Split(',').Skip(2));
```

Comment: @tmax np, I'm sure I'll be able to use it in the future to now!

Answer (score 2):

The code "testString.IndexOf(",", 0, 3)" does not find the 3rd comma. It find the first comma starting at position 0 looking at the first 3 positions (i.e. character positions 0,1,2).

If you want the part after the last comma use something like this:

```
Dim testString As String = "part, description, order, get this text"
Dim result As String = ""
result = testString.Substring(testString.LastIndexOf(",") + 1)
```

Note the +1 to move to the character after the comma. You should really also find the index first and add checks to confirm that the index is not -1 and index < testString.Length too.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives(I assume you want all the text after last comma):

**Using LastIndexOf:**

```
' You can add code to check if the LastIndexOf returns a positive number
Dim result As String = testString.SubString(testString.LastIndexOf(",")+1)
```

**Regular Expressions:**

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(testString, "(.*,)(.*)$", "$2")
```

Comment: all text after third comma, Dim testString As String = "part, description, order, get this text, and this text"

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of `indexOf` is the number of charcters to search. You are searching for `,` starting at `0` for `3` characters - that is searching the string `par` for a comma which does not exist so the returned index is `-1`, hence your error. I think that you would need to use some recursion:

```
Dim testString As String = "part, description, order, get this text"
Dim index As Int32 = 0

For i As Int32 = 1 To 3    
  index = testString.IndexOf(","c, index + 1)
  If index < 0 Then
    ' Not enough commas. Handle this.
  End If
Next
Dim result As String = testString.Substring(index + 1)
```

Comment: I have done it this way before but looking for that one line method of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The IndexOf function only finds the "**First**" of the specified character. The last parameter (in your case 3) specifies how many characters to examine and not the occurence.

Refer to [Find Nth occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571716/find-nth-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

The function specified here finds the Nth occurance of a character. Then use the substring function on the occurance returned.

Alternative , you can also use regular expression to  find the nth occurance.

```
public static int NthIndexOf(this string target, string value, int n)
    {
        Match m = Regex.Match(target, "((" + value + ").*?){" + n + "}");

        if (m.Success)
        {
            return m.Groups[2].Captures[n - 1].Index;
        }
        else
        {
             return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is what you are looking for**

```
    Dim testString As String = "part, description, order, get this text"
    Dim resultArray As String() = testString.Split(New Char() {","c}, 3)
    Dim resultString As String = resultArray(2)
```