# VB .net - shortest and fastest way to find Nth occurrence of char in string?

Tags: vb.net

What is the professional way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: The professional way would be to get paid for it.

Comment: Shortest code, fastest algorithm, most memory-efficient algorithm, most readable code?

Comment: @SteveDog - shortest and fastest please.

Comment: You can't have both.  Make a choice.

Comment: If you are looking for fastest, I'd say the answer by @MikeC is as fast as you are going to get (outside of more extreme measures such as indexing).

Answer (score 7):

I've shamelessly ripped off the example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571716/find-nth-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string) and converted it from C# to VB.net.

```
Public Function GetNthIndex(s As String, t As Char, n As Integer) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
        If s(i) = t Then
            count += 1
            If count = n Then
                Return i
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function
```

Comment: There's no shame in efficiency!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to do it with Linq.

```
Public Function GetNthIndex(searchString As String, charToFind As Char, n As Integer) As Integer
    Dim charIndexPair = searchString.Select(Function(c,i) new with {.Character = c, .Index = i}) _
                                    .Where(Function(x) x.Character = charToFind) _
                                    .ElementAtOrDefault(n-1)
    Return If(charIndexPair IsNot Nothing, charIndexPair.Index, -1)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim searchString As String = "Assessment"
Dim index As Integer = GetNthIndex(searchString, "s", 4) 'Returns 5
```

Comment: Does this take into account that there *aren't* n occurrences in the string?  What if they ask for the 4th occurrence but there are only 3?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: I edited the code so that it returns -1 in case there aren't n occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

My Version of Andew's but I believe this takes into account if the first character is the character you are looking for

```
 Public Function GetNthIndexStringFunc(s As String, t As String, n As Integer) As Integer
        Dim newFound As Integer = -1
        For i As Integer = 1 To n
            newFound = s.IndexOf(t, newFound + 1)
            If newFound = -1 Then
                Return newFound
            End If
        Next
        Return newFound
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This a recursive solution to finding the nth occurrence of a character
Integrity checks have been added.
The proposed solution is not the panacia, however it is in the reality quite simple and clean, as far as it has been tested.

```
Sub nthTest()
Dim mStr As String
Dim iPos As Integer

  mStr = "aa / bb / cc / dd / ee / ff"
  iPos = nthOccurrence(mStr, "/", 3)
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function nthOccurrence(mainStr As String, findStr As String, nth As Integer, Optional nthOcc As Integer, _
                      Optional ind As Integer) As Integer
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'mainStr: string to be searched
'findStr: string to be foun. Thsi can be a single character or a string
'nth    : number of occurrence
'nthOcc : occurrences found so far. The user does not have to worry
'         about it as it used internaly during the recursion, and is set automatically
'ind    : position to start the search in the string. The user does not have to worry
'         about it as it used internaly during the recursion, and is set automatically
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim not1stRun As Boolean
Dim i   As Integer
Dim occ As Integer

  ' Perform integrity checks
  If not1stRun = False Then
    not1stRun = True
    ' Find number of occurances of the "findStr" in the "mainStr"
    occ = Len(mainStr) - Len(Replace(mainStr, findStr, ""))
    If occ < nth Then
      MsgBox "There not that many occurrences of " & """" & findStr & """" & " in the main string" & vbCrLf & _
             "Function will terminate." & vbCrLf & "Please apply corrections"
      Exit Function
    End If
    ' Occurance should be >= 1
    If nth <= 0 Then
      MsgBox "Number of occurrences should be >= 1" & vbCrLf & _
             "Function will terminate." & vbCrLf & "Please apply corrections"
      Exit Function
    End If
  End If
  
  ' If requested occurrence is not found yet
  If nthOcc < nth Then
    If ind = 0 Then
      ' if it is the first time search here
      i = InStr(mainStr, findStr)
    Else
      ' if it is not the first time search here
      i = InStr(ind, mainStr, findStr)
    End If
    ' If occurrence is found
    If i > 0 Then
      ' Increase occurrences found
      nthOcc = nthOcc + 1
      ' Increase index for next occurrence.
      ' Add 1, so to start looking after the last occurrence
      ind = i + 1
      ' recursive call of the finction
      nthOccurrence = nthOccurrence(mainStr, findStr, nth, nthOcc, ind)
    End If
  Else
    ' END recursion here, return last position by deducting 1,
    '     that was added for the recursive call
    nthOccurrence = ind - 1
  End If
End Function
```