# Shortening a string of numbers

Tags: c#

I have the following sequence of numbers:

[image]

You can see that those numbers a lot. I want to shorten that string. Let's say if the string contains more than 20 numbers, it should display 18 numbers, then "..." and then the last two of the sequence.

I could probably do that by adding those numbers in a `List<int>` or `HashSet<int>` (HashSet might be faster in this case), but I think it will be slow.

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

for (...)
{
    temp.Append($"{number} ");
}

var sequence = temp.ToString();
```

Example of what I want:

```
7 9 12 16 18 21 25 27 30 34 36 39 43 45 48 52 54 57 ... 952 954
```

Note that I want only *fast ways*.

Comment: Can you put the declaration of the sequence of numbers into your question? A lot of people (myself included) can't see imgur stuff at work because it's blocked...

Comment: If you using LINQ then take first 18 element from your collection and then take last 2 element from your collection and concate them with ....

Comment: Are those numbers in one single string? Or are they already in some kind of collection?

Comment: he says "string"  after the pic

Comment: I just wanted to be sure, since the code is missing

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's a space-separated sequence of numbers in a string. `"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"` (but much longer)

Comment: Why are you so concerned about "fast"? How fast is "fast"? How slow is too slow? Because code that is readable, maintainable and verifyable might save you more in the long run.

Comment: And if it's got 21 items, it should end in `18 ... 20 21`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version is about 8 times faster than the other answers and allocates only about 6% as much memory. I think you'll be hard-pressed to find a faster version:

```
static string Truncated(string input)
{
    var indexOfEighteenthSpace = IndexOfCharSeekFromStart(input, ' ', 18);
    if (indexOfEighteenthSpace <= 0) return input;

    var indexOfSecondLastSpace = IndexOfCharSeekFromEnd(input, ' ', 2);
    if (indexOfSecondLastSpace <= 0) return input;

    if (indexOfSecondLastSpace <= indexOfEighteenthSpace) return input;

    var leadingSegment = input.AsSpan().Slice(0, indexOfEighteenthSpace);
    var trailingSegment = input.AsSpan().Slice(indexOfSecondLastSpace + 1);

    return string.Concat(leadingSegment, " ... ", trailingSegment);

    static int IndexOfCharSeekFromStart(string input, char value, int count)
    {
       var startIndex = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           startIndex = input.IndexOf(value, startIndex + 1);
           if (startIndex <= 0) return startIndex;
       }

        return startIndex;
    }

    static int IndexOfCharSeekFromEnd(string input, char value, int count)
    {
       var endIndex = input.Length - 1;
       for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           endIndex = input.LastIndexOf(value, endIndex - 1);
           if (endIndex <= 0) return endIndex;
       }

        return endIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is AsSpan?  not seen that before

Comment: @TimRutter It's a .Net Core 3 thing. https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-optimising-code-using-span-t

Comment: @TimRutter: [C# Span](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx)

Comment: A `Span` represents a contiguous block of memory. `AsSpan()` on a string returns a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, which maps to the underlying chars in the original string. Slicing the ReadOnlySpan lets me effectively build a substring without allocating a new string to hold the substring, instead it just points at the original memory used by the initial string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson it launched with Core 2.1, but it's not only available in Core - you can also use it in Framework and friends with https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/

Comment: Thank you for that solution! I will accept this because it's the fastest

Comment: @yaakov, how would that solution work if I wanted to add commas between the numbers and a dot in the end?

Comment: @nop that would be quite a different algorithm to assemble the final string.

Answer (score 3):

### Small individual steps

How do I make a list from this sequence (string)?

```
var myList = myOriginalSequence.Split(' ').ToList();
```

How do you take the first 18 numbers from a list?

```
var first18Numbers = myList.Take(18);
```

How do you take the last 2 numbers from a list?

```
var last2Numbers = myList.Skip(myList.Count() - 2);
```

How do you ensure that this is only done when there are more than 20 numbers in the list?

```
if(myList.Count() > 20)
```

How do you make a new sequence string from a list?

```
var myNewSequence = String.Join(" ", myList);
```

---

### Putting it all together

```
var myList = myOriginalSequence.Split(' ').ToList();

string myNewSequence;

if(myList.Count() > 20)
{
    var first18Numbers = myList.Take(18);
    var first18NumbersString = String.Join(" ", first18Numbers);

    var last2Numbers = myList.Skip(myList.Count() - 2);
    var last2NumbersString = String.Join(" ", last2Numbers);

    myNewSequence = $"{first18NumbersString} ... {last2NumbersString}"
}
else
{
    myNewSequence = myOriginalSequence;
}

Console.WriteLine(myNewSequence);
```

Comment: split has just iterated through the entire string (which may be huge).  He has asked for performance

Comment: Split will produce an array with all the part when only the top 18 and last 2 are needed.

Comment: I'm not convinced that splitting the entire string is the most performant approach.

Comment: @Flater `string.Length` does not iterate over the string's content.

Comment: Thank you for that solution! @yaakov's solution seems to be the fastest

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help :

```
    public IEnumerable<string> ShortenList(string input)
    {
       List<int> list = input.Split(" ").Select(x=>int.Parse(x)).ToList();
        if (list.Count > 20)
        {
            List<string> trimmedStringList = list.Take(18).Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToList();
            trimmedStringList.Add("...");
            trimmedStringList.Add(list[list.Count-2].ToString());
            trimmedStringList.Add(list[list.Count - 1].ToString());

            return trimmedStringList;
        }

        return list.Select(x => x.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Note that the check should be `> 20`, not `> 19`. If you have exactly 20 items, you don't need the ellipsis since you're still going to list all the numbers (the first 18 + the last 2 = 20 in total)

Comment: You're completely right, anyway, your answer is much more detailed than mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the speed on this would be like but as a wild suggestion, you said the numbers come in string format and it looks like they're seperated by spaces. You could get the index of the 19th space (to display 18 numbers) using any of the methods found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571744/8306962), and substring from index 0 to that index and concatenate 3 dots. Something like this:

```
numberListString.SubString(0, IndexOfNth(numberListString, ' ', 19)) + "..."
```

(Not accurate code, adding or subtracting indexes or adjusting values (19) may be required).

EDIT: Just saw that after the dots you wanted to have the last 2 numbers, you can use the same technique! Just concatenate that result again.

NOTE: I used this whacky technique because the OP said they wanted fast ways, I'm just offering a potential option to benchmark :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public string Shorten(string str, int startCount, int endCount)
    {
        //first remove any leading or trailing whitespace
        str = str.Trim();

        //find the first startCount numbers by using IndexOf space
        //i.e. this counts the number of spaces from the start until startCount is achieved
        int spaceCount = 1;
        int startInd = str.IndexOf(' ');
        while (spaceCount < startCount && startInd > -1)
        {
            startInd = str.IndexOf(' ',startInd +1);
            spaceCount++;
        }

        //find the last endCount numbers by using LastIndexOf space
        //i.e. this counts the number of spaces from the end until endCount is achieved
        int lastSpaceCount = 1;
        int lastInd = str.LastIndexOf(' ');
        while (lastSpaceCount < endCount && lastInd > -1)
        {
            lastInd =  str.LastIndexOf(' ', lastInd - 1);
            lastSpaceCount++;
        }

        //if the start ind or end ind are -1 or if lastInd <= startIndjust return the str 
        //as its not long enough and so doesn't need shortening
        if (startInd == -1 || lastInd == -1 || lastInd <= startInd) return str;

        //otherwise return the required shortened string
        return $"{str.Substring(0, startInd)} ... {str.Substring(lastInd + 1)}";
    }
```

the output of this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(Shorten("123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123",4,3));
```

is:

> 123 123 123 123 ... 123 123 123

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon. Explain what you've done rather than having OP copy/paste your answer without learning what the actual solution to the question is.

Comment: I've added some comments

Comment: @Paul that's not really constructive, now is it? A code-only answer is a nice exercise for the answerer, but not really helpful for the OP and other later visitors who want to learn from it.

Comment: Well i think its more useful than no answer.  I agree comments (and I've added some) are helpful but a code only answer is not totally unhelpful.

Comment: @CodeCaster - The code was fine [even as was](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58746366/revisions) - the variables were properly named, code sequences were easy to follow (judging by the original post), indentation was in place, and now the comments have been added - self-documenting code!  The only thing I find a little off about it (but that's more because I prefer concrete declarations) is that the `var` keyword is used to imply variable type, but that's the way of the C# world these days.

Comment: @Paul agreed, I've replaced var with explicit types

Comment: @TimRutter - no, I wouldn't change it, as it shows different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: @Paul I actually don't like var for simple types like int.   I only use it where there the type is absolutely clear eg var rect = new Rectangle();

Comment: @Paul no, the initial code was not fine. Sure, it is easy to follow **if you know what the code is doing**. If you're not, you're going to have to parse the code and rebuild the mental model that the writer has. Variables named `lastSpaceCount`, `endCount` and `lastInd` don't tell me we're going to count the spaces from the end of the string as clearly as, well, the words I just used.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way that prevents iteration through the entire string of numbers and is reasonably fast.

Strings in .NET are basically an array of chars, and can be referenced on an individual basis using array referencing (`[1..n]`).  This can be used to our advantage by simply testing for the correct number of spaces from the start and end respectively.

There are no niceties in the code, but they could be optimised later (for instance, by ensuring that there's actually something in the string, that the string is trimmed etc.).

The functions below could also be optimised to a single function if you're feeling energetic.

```cs
string finalNumbers = GetStartNumbers(myListOfNumbers, 18);
if(finalNumbers.EndsWith(" ... "))
    finalNumbers += GetEndNumbers(myListOfNumbers, 2);


public string GetStartNumbers(string listOfNumbers, int collectThisManyNumbers) 
{
    int spaceCounter = 0;    //  The current count of spaces
    int charPointer = 0;     //  The current character in the string
    //  Loop through the list of numbers until we either run out of characters
    //  or get to the appropriate 'space' position...
    while(spaceCounter < collectThisManyNumbers && charPointer <= listOfNumbers.Length)
    {
        //  The following line will add 1 to spaceCounter if the character at the
        //  charPointer position is a space. The charPointer is then incremented...
        spaceCounter += ( listOfNumbers[charPointer++]==' ' ? 1 : 0 );
    }
    //  Now return our value based on the last value of charPointer. Note that
    //  if our string doesn't have the right number of elements, then it will
    //  not be suffixed with ' ... '
    if(spaceCounter < collectThisManyNumbers) 
        return listOfNumbers.Substring(0, charPointer - 1);
    else
        return listOfNumbers.Substring(0, charPointer - 1) + " ... ";
}

public string GetEndNumbers(string listOfNumbers, int collectThisManyNumbers) 
{
    int spaceCounter = 0;                       //  The current count of spaces
    int charPointer = listOfNumbers.Length;     //  The current character in the string
    //  Loop through the list of numbers until we either run out of characters
    //  or get to the appropriate 'space' position...
    while(spaceCounter < collectThisManyNumbers && charPointer >= 0)
    {
        //  The following line will add 1 to spaceCounter if the character at the
        //  charPointer position is a space. The charPointer is then decremented...
        spaceCounter += ( listOfNumbers[charPointer--]==' ' ? 1 : 0 );
    }
    //  Now return our value based on the last value of charPointer...
    return listOfNumbers.Substring(charPointer);
}
```

Some people find the use of `++` and `--` objectionable but it's up to you. If you want to do the maths and logic, knock yourself out!

Please note that this code is quite long because it's commented to the far end of a fart.