# How do I get the web sites running in the current application pool by WMI?

Tags: c#, iis, wmi, web-administration

I am trying to find out which web sites are running an application pool. `MicrosoftIISv2/WebServerSetting` only offers AppPoolId property and all of the valuse are *DefaultAppPool* . I can see all of these application pools are running different web sites on IIS. How can I get the web sites running on an application pool by WMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it can be done with `EnumAppsInPool` method. Here's the code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetWebSitesRunningOnApplicationPool(ManagementScope scope, string applicationPoolName)
{
    //get application names from application pool
    string path = string.Format("IIsApplicationPool.Name='W3SVC/APPPOOLS/{0}'", applicationPoolName);
    ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath(path);
    ManagementObject classInstance = new ManagementObject(scope, managementPath, null);
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("EnumAppsInPool", null, null);


    //get web server names from application names
    IEnumerable<string> nameList = (outParams.Properties["Applications"].Value as string[]) //no null reference exception even there is no application running
                                   .Where(item => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) //but you get empty strings so they are filtered
                                   .ToList() //you get something like /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT
                                   .Select(item => item.Slice(item.NthIndexOf("/", 2) + 1, item.NthIndexOf("/", 4))); //your WebServer.Name is between 2nd and 4th slahes


    //get server comments from names
    List<string> serverCommentList = new List<string>();
    foreach (string name in nameList)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery(string.Format("SELECT ServerComment FROM IIsWebServerSetting WHERE Name = '{0}'", name)));

        serverCommentList.AddRange(from ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get() select queryObj["ServerComment"].ToString());
    }

    return serverCommentList;
}
```

And the string extensions taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186653/c-indexof-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string/187394#187394) and [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-slice)

```
    public static int NthIndexOf(this string target, string value, int n)
    {
        int result = -1;

        Match m = Regex.Match(target, "((" + value + ").*?){" + n + "}");

        if (m.Success)
        {
            result = m.Groups[2].Captures[n - 1].Index;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string Slice(this string source, int start, int end)
    {
        if (end < 0) 
        {
            end = source.Length + end;
        }

        int len = end - start;               
        return source.Substring(start, len); 
    }
```